# infer argument types of a function based on object keys

Tags: typescript

With the code below I am trying to make the argument type of `fn` be inferred based on the value of `args`.

I need `good` to be inferred as boolean, `num` as number and `bad` to be an error.

Right now they all have the type `string | number | boolean` and there is no error.

```
type WithArgs<
  Args extends {
    [key: string]: { value: [string, string | number | boolean] };
  } = {
    [key: string]: { value: [string, string | number | boolean] };
  },
  Arg extends keyof Args = keyof Args
> = {
  args: Args;
  fn: (params: { [key in Arg]: Args[Arg]["value"][1] }) => void;
};

const configs: WithArgs[] = [{
  args: { good: { value: ["bool", true] } },
  fn: ({ good, bad }) => {}
}, {
  args: { num: { value: ["number", 5] } },
  fn: ({ num }) => {}
}];
```

Comment: You can't do this, it is a limitation of typescript, only functions really have good inference as noted by David. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378737/9611958 for a thorough explanation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript can only infer types for functions. Since you are trying to type a non-function, then your generic type must take in an argument.

If I provide the first argument for the type, then `good` can only be true, and we get an error for bad that says "TS2339: Property 'bad' does not exist on type '{ good: true; }'."

```js
const configs: WithArgs<{ good: { value: ['bool', true] } }>[] = [{
  args: { good: { value: ["bool", true] } },
  fn: ({ good, bad }) => {}
}];
```

Of course I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. I'm very interested to know .

EDIT ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4B4AqA%20KBeKBvAWACgpSoBtAawhAC4olg4BLAOwQF168oA3AQwA2AVwj1yjFuwA0UNBygBfANzEVxYqEhQA6s2AALeMhTEysKBAAewCKwAmSWIlTDWlVgHsA7qyy5CEnMyKhp6STZObj4hUXEImQYmSKgAHyhWYQBbACMIODSoHM9PQQh%20VgV1INJFaTMyY0sbO0coahBPADMLXA7u2AbSf3whqH4XehhVGqgu1noACjAJ-iykaNCQKDZnKNhyYw5yACIBEQgT44BGKoBKHCxeT2Z7GeriAGNPVkYob30RhcOCgKAAwrIYM1bA4nMZUGCMLIAGLQ1pOfo9GAYRbfVhdZgIeh6QzwlAwFEYB7YLB4gkIGZfH5-NjnV4ggGklyLQLmCbIaIIEr2aLnOIUE7FUonWRMURVJT1WbzJY8IWeeyyHL8exKalYPCKKAAemNUAACnBPJA4KAoABybX2e1QeyeCBOLzAZrMP4-KBaaD2tXC%20hSsoVZRKe1qO6MoiBqAAcQgwBJQJMmBBaDRsN0gLJbC6%20VgsiLJeRWAA-PmuSYKVBK1B6KwILx8vG8X9ORmkPACrh0Lm2umyWS3B4fH5ZAkEIVMrl8hhyBwcQA6Dd0wkbOT6qBb5BrrL8MCLHvwh78Jw8cjMHasdo0AbyegptMFlzoW%20rpSd5nepADE8YRBHsGBBCQTwACEIAASVYNldVwc8XH7RYxl5YJSH5HcQw1UVYjECVwxlAM4HlJRFTGcwVSgHkoHVTUih1PVHnwRQxjqUZZj5SZ8AybICIucQTgXPI4FIgBWBU6moshaPohdWJpdjOOIOMTTNLxLDgK04CcEBU2bdCiCZX5vTgCAAEdhGYSykCgkpBBBQDgNA8DIJg%20DEPIAAGDg13mejGPoe1ZxdRQNNNOQAGUACYAGY4ri%20g0HAINwp2T1PG9K8kEJVh%20ByMoA08AN0odcNylYe01zMv4nQAEXdJAADkcoAUSsX1vVwVyQLAiDoLghChFePyAqCngnVCzLIqjaK0HihKABZJKmRBsjsb0BkTYNmJFJIpAZaMsoyHLxiQfKEEK4roGAMqVjgNZUxLXaKv2kKiic6qo0UWr6os6zbPs1rsnE81ViyV6BwYICBo84bvLG%20xyFuQLWEUwSHWuCKorNJbEuS1KPsy31ztyq6CqKkqHvK7R7TE-IAdMoggA)):

I took my own advice. Knowing that Typescript *can* infer types from functions, then all we need to do is create a function.

First, I added a definition for `Args`, and updated the `WithArgs` type:

```js
type Args<T> = {
    [key: string]: { value: [string, T] };
};

type WithArgs<
    A extends Args<unknown> = {
        [key: string]: { value: [string, string | number | boolean] };
    },
    Arg extends keyof A = keyof A
    > = {
    args: A;
    fn: (params: { [key in Arg]: A[Arg]["value"][1] }) => void;
};
```

Then, I define a function which infers the types for a single config:

```js
const withArgs = <C, A extends Args<C>, F extends keyof A>(config: WithArgs<A, F>) => config;
```

Now we get an error for `bad` as desired:

```js
const invalid = withArgs({
    args: { good: { value: ["bool", true] } },
    fn: ({ good, bad }) => {} // Property 'bad' does not exist on type '{ good: boolean; }'
});
```

Of course, you want to be able to define an array of these configs. So we can define a function which will properly type an array:

```js
type GetWithArgs<T> = T extends WithArgs<infer A, infer F> ? WithArgs<A, F> : never;

const withArgsArr = <T extends WithArgs<Args<unknown>, string | number>[]>(...configs: T) => configs.map(withArgs) as { [i in keyof T]: GetWithArgs<T[i]> };
```

Now, I haven't figured this out yet, but the errors don't appear to be thrown when you declare the entire config this way. The type errors only occur when you then refer to a specific config. I would love for someone to help clarify this behavior (edit: [I've now asked the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525645/generic-spread-tuple-type-does-not-throw-errors-until-specific-element-is-refere)).

```js
const shouldAlsoBeInvalid = withArgsArr(
    {
        args: { good: { value: ["bool", true] } },
        fn: ({ good, bad }) => {}
    }, {
        args: { num: { value: ["number", 5] } },
        fn: ({ num }) => {}
    }
); // no errors yet :(

const requiresBool = shouldAlsoBeInvalid[0].fn({ good: 'string' }); // TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
const badDoesNotExist = shouldAlsoBeInvalid[0].fn({ bad: 'string' }); // TS2345: Argument of type '{ bad: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ good: boolean; }'.
const requiresNumberParameter = shouldAlsoBeInvalid[1].fn({ num: '1' }); // TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: I don't want to do this. The whole point is to not have pass the generic argument. `configs` is an array, `args` can be different in each entry

Comment: I think I (mostly) solved your question using functions. If you can figure out why `shouldAlsoBeInvalid` doesn't have an error until a specific config is referenced that'd help me out, too .