# Generic spread tuple type does not throw errors until specific element is referenced

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript4.0

There's a few type definitions I didn't want to put in the question, so here's a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4B4AqA%20KBeKBvAWACgpSoBtAawhAC4olg4BLAOwQF168oA3AQwA2AVwj1yjFuwA0UNBygBfANzEVxYqEhQA6s2AALeMhTEysKBAAewCKwAmSWIlTDWlVgHsA7qyy5CEnMyKhp6STZObj4hUXEImQYmSKgAHyhWYQBbACMIODSoHM9PQQh%20VgV1INJFaTMyY0sbO0coahBPADMLXA7u2AbSf3whqH4XehhVGqgu1noACjAJ-iykaNCQKDZnKNhyYw5yACIBEQgT44BGKoBKHCxeT2Z7GeriAGNPVkYob30RhcOCgKAAwrIYM1bA4nMZUGCMLIAGLQ1pOfo9GAYRbfVhdZgIeh6QzwlAwFEYB7YLB4gkIGZfH5-NjnV4ggGklyLQLmCbIaIIEr2aLnOIUE7FUonWRMURVJT1WbzJY8IWeeyyHL8exKalYPCKKAAemNUAACnBPJA4KAoABybX2e1QeyeCBOLzAZrMP4-KBaaD2tXC%20hSsoVZRKe1qO6MoiBqAAcQgwBJQJMmBBaDRsN0gLJbC6%20VgsiLJeRWAA-PmuSYKVBK1B6KwILx8vG8X9ORmkPACrh0Lm2umyWS3B4fH5ZAkEIVMrl8hhyBwcQA6Dd0wkbOT6qBb5BrrL8MCLHvwh78JzkDdrnjkZg7VjtGgDeT0FNpgsudAP1dKDhO2Zb0kAMTxhEEewYEEJBPAAIQgABJVg2V1XBzxcftFjGXlglIfkdxDDVRViMQJXDGUAzgeUlEVMZzBVKAeSgdVNSKHU9UefBFDGOpRlmPlJnwDJshIi5xBOBc8jgSiAFYFTqeiyEY5iF04mluN44g4xNM0vEsOArTgJwQFTZtsKIJlfm9OAIAAR2EZhbKQOCSkEEFQPAyDoNghDkNQ8gAAYODXeZmNY%20h7VnF1FB0005AAZQAJgAZiSpL6DQcAg2inZPU8b0ryQQlWH4HIygDTwA2yh1w3KVh7TXKy-idAARd0kAAOQKgBRKxfW9XBPIgqCYPgpCUKEV4gpCsKeCdSLctiqN4rQZKUoAFlkqZEGyOxvQGRNg3YkUkikBlozyjICvGJBioQUryugYAqpWOA1lTEtDpq46IqKNz6qjRRGuamz7Mc5zOuyaTzVWLJPoHBgwJGnzxv8qb7HIW5QtYVTRIda4Yris01tS9LMp%203LfWuwq7pKsqKpe6rtHtKT8hByyiCAA)

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517296/infer-argument-types-of-a-function-based-on-object-keys/64519581#64519581), I came across a weird scenario.

I need to assert the type of each element in a tuple. Right now, this function I have only shows errors when I reference a specific property (since I assert the return value), but there are no complaints from the linter for the function's parameters.

```js
const withArgsArr = <T extends WithArgs<Args<unknown>, string | number>[]>(...configs: T) => configs.map(withArgs) as { [i in keyof T]: GetWithArgs<T[i]> };

const shouldAlsoBeInvalid = withArgsArr(
    {
        args: { good: { value: ["bool", true] } },
        fn: ({ good, bad }) => {}
    }, {
        args: { num: { value: ["number", 5] } },
        fn: ({ num }) => {}
    }
); // no errors yet :(

const requiresBool = shouldAlsoBeInvalid[0].fn({ good: 'string' }); // TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
const badDoesNotExist = shouldAlsoBeInvalid[0].fn({ bad: 'string' }); // TS2345: Argument of type '{ bad: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ good: boolean; }'.
const requiresNumberParameter = shouldAlsoBeInvalid[1].fn({ num: '1' }); // TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Individually, I know how to assert the type properly:

```js
const invalid = withArgs({
    args: { good: { value: ["bool", true] } },
    fn: ({ good, bad }) => {} // Property 'bad' does not exist on type '{ good: boolean; }'
});
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to generically assert that incoming type for `withArgsArr`. Something like:

```js
const withArgsArr = <T extends *an array of WithArgs elements, for which each are a valid WithArgs element*>(...configs: T) => configs.map(withArgs) as { [i in keyof T]: GetWithArgs<T[i]> };
```

Comment: ehhh, I think the problem here is that the compiler can't infer quite as much as you need it to.  You want the compiler to infer the type of the argument to each element's `fn` property, as well as the literal `["bool", true]` as a tuple, both of which get in the way.  If you very strongly and explicitly type the arguments and fix up some of the typings you can get an error where you want it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Bmxq8W), but I doubt it's worth it (the strong typings, that is.  fixing up the typings is worth it, imo).

Comment: I'd be happy to write up some kind of answer but this really doesn't feel like a [mcve].  Like, the `{ [K in keyof A]: A[Arg]["value"][1] }` seems kind of bizarre to me (do you really want `Arg` in there?).  Anything that's not directly relevant to the error should probably be removed from the example (if you can get the same error when you remove something, then remove it).  Good luck!