# TypeScript: How to convert object back and forth between types

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, casting

Let say that I have two types

```
type A = {
  fi_name: string;
  l_name: string;
  f_name: string;
}

type B = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  fullName: string;
}
```

Is there a way to easily convert an object back and forth between these types?

**Extra internet points** if the answers also handles nested types and/or can be implemented using an expressjs middleware.

Comment: Don't you think of a simple way to create two mapping functions? Anyway you need a mapping that describes pairs like `fl_name` - `firstName`.

Comment: I'm trying avoid having to create 2 functions, i.e. A2B() and B2A(). I was hoping that there is a module or some build in way to be able to simplify things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure any internet points are worth the effort of solving the issue for arbitrarily nested properties.  In order to do this programmatically, you need your function to accept a "mapping" schema from one type to the other.  For example, given your type `A` and `type B`, you might do this:

```
const aToB = makeMapper<A, B>()({
  f_name: "fullName",
  fi_name: "firstName",
  l_name: "lastName"
} as const);
```

Here you can see that the hypothetical `makeMapper` function is generic and lets you specify the desired input type (`A`) and the desired output type (`B`), and then the output of that accepts the mapping schema, where each property name is mapped to another property name.  (This is a curried function because TypeScript lacks partial specification of type parameters; you need type parameters for input and output, as well as one for the mapping.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378737/2887218) for more info.) (Also, you need that [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to make sure the compiler is aware of the string literal values like `"fullName"` and does not widen them to `string`).

If you do something wrong in your mapping, you'd expect some kind of error message:

```
const badMapper = makeMapper<A, B>()({
  f_name: "fullName",
  fi_name: "firstName",
  l_name: "lostName",
} as const); // error!
// 'Invalid<{ lastName: "missing or misspelled property key"; }>'
```

Here I wrote `lostName` instead of `lastName` so I'd want an error on the above type telling me that I got the `lastName` property wrong in some way.

For object properties, you need the mapping schema to accept not just a renamed key but also a mapper for the object type.  For example:

```
interface AccountA {
  user: A
}
interface AccountB {
  user: B
}
const accountAToAccountB = makeMapper<AccountA, AccountB>()({
  user: ["user", aToB]
} as const);
```

Here the `AccountA` to `AccountB` mapper keeps the property named `user` but changes the type from `A` to `B` with the `aToB` mapper we created earlier.

Then, to actually use the resultant mapper forwards and backwards would look like this:

```
const a: AccountA = {
  user: {
    fi_name: "Harry",
    l_name: "Potter",
    f_name: "Harry Potter"
  }
}

const b: AccountB = accountAToAccountB.map(a);

console.log(b);
/* {
  "user": {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "fullName": "Harry Potter"
  }
}  */

const aAgain: AccountA = accountAToAccountB.reverseMap(b);
console.log(aAgain);
/* {
  "user": {
    "fi_name": "Harry",
    "l_name": "Potter",
    "f_name": "Harry Potter"
  }
} */
```

Right?

---

Well you *can* do this in TypeScript, but the typings are pretty ugly and involved, and the implementation needs lots of type assertions.  Here's how one might do it:

```
class Mapper<T extends object, M extends ObjectMapping<T>> {
  constructor(public mapping: M) { }
  map(obj: T): Mapped<T, M> {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
      if (!(k in this.mapping)) return [k, v];
      const m = this.mapping[k as keyof T];
      if (Array.isArray(m)) return [m[0], m[1] ? m[1].map(v) : v];
      return [m, v];
    })) as any;
  }
  reverseMap(obj: Mapped<T, M>): T {
    const revMapping: Record<string, any> = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(this.mapping).map(([k, m]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(m)) return [m[0], [k, m[1]]];
      return [m, k];
    }));
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
      if (!(k in revMapping)) return [k, v];
      const m = revMapping[k];
      if (Array.isArray(m)) return [m[0], m[1] ? m[1].reverseMap(v) : v];
      return [m, v];
    })) as any;
  }
}

type ObjectMapping<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? readonly [PropertyKey, Mapper<T[K], any>?] : PropertyKey
}

type Mapped<T extends object, M extends ObjectMapping<T>> = {
  [K in keyof T as GetKey<M[K]>]: GetVal<M[K], T[K]>
} extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
type GetKey<P> = P extends PropertyKey ? P : P extends readonly [PropertyKey, any?] ? P[0] : never;
type GetVal<P, V> = P extends PropertyKey ? V :
  P extends readonly [PropertyKey, Mapper<any, any>] ? V extends object ? Mapped<V, P[1]['mapping']> : V : V;

type Invalid<Err> = {
  errMsg: Err
}

function makeMapper<T extends object, U extends object>() {
  return <M extends ObjectMapping<T>>(mapping: (Mapped<T, M> extends U ? M : M & Invalid<
    { [K in keyof U as K extends keyof Mapped<T, M> ? Mapped<T, M>[K] extends U[K] ? never : K : K]:
      K extends keyof Mapped<T, M> ? Mapped<T, M>[K] extends U[K] ? never :
      ["wrong property type", U[K], "vs", Mapped<T, M>[K]] : "missing or misspelled property key" }
  >)) => new Mapper<T, M>(mapping as M)
}
```

Should I bother to explain how each piece of that works?  The typings are basically a recursive use of TS4.1's [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types). The implementation is also recursively walking down through the `mapping` schema and applying the mappings to the input object's entries.

Getting the compiler to produce useful error messages in the face of such complex typings is not straightforward since there are currently no "throw/invalid" types in TypeScript (see [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689)) so I had to use a workaround.

There are probably *all kinds* of edge cases there, when it comes to object types whose properties are unions of primitives and other object types, or when property names conflict, etc.  Something like this would need lots of testing in both the type system and at runtime before you even consider using it in any sort of production environment.

So you might consider the scope of your actual use case and whether you really want some all-purpose remapper, or if a more hardcoded approach would be a better fit.  For a pair of types like your `A` and `B`, the above implementation is probably overkill even if there are no edge cases.  For your actual use case?  Only you can say.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/PQ4AgGQSQIQJQIJwJpgMIHkAiBRAUHgMYA2AhgM7lgCypADnQKYBOAPACpiMAeALowDsAJlQD2AIwBWjQrwA0NLn0EiwGKTN60GASwEBzDgD4jYAN54wYQqIHlezAK6zRzABR1H44jsJgAtvR0evoAXDQAlOZgAL6WAfRuEpLh7BHh2kxCHArUphZWVsyMvI7MAmoasgB0AGbMov44Ag46jORu6tI1gq3tSVIR1YF0bm4A2gDWCgBuALpRALz58YVgOrVgbgCEbpPrFbwAFjrkw0EhEVHFpeVgU7NzANyrhTZ2vAFgi2DHp+e6AxTMAUMCTRgAT1Em3Yz1eVg2WwQzGYpAh1VOyNRELc-iuYBuZQq4384wADHMFKSAIxzMAAfgC41pALcMyi4XmLzWRRKRPu-ke3MKMXxoNIAghwrivJmLHIjG0AxSNCCjGy7FyRnSYE4BTetnsBMYM0yIXCcBkrmy9mYIQUEohph+XU0dQaTRadv6rp6XraHT+ZxGwQMQxGYweAQW3xWPPWmzcWLRGPIyZxeOufLuJPJlPu0yZtLmcPjhJzgrBpZFV2FvNuFV9vHdjWafQ6TeqvW9HWS4cSE0L8yWcZ5iJ2ewOxtNFzDWYbBaF8Oshs+-m+07NQMm1bW4-TqfTuPx5eJpIpVOZdMZNLm1WKcuYCqV7LAnN3hVPAqXa1FUXFkrSngcR4LwEJMJU3RaLOhicDw-DCGIVS8M65jxOMADSU7glCMJzKkmF0vBKhIVBDLGqQQi2MQEL3AACg0TDMGBGGQrkapsOwhEOpKRj0nS4QMaITEsZCwEEGBEGZOqHBKAhqjJJouRySRkGaFusEmBu+qYdhkLQrqIJUAA4iUrEQqw1CEUY+FgKZvAAGqkMQlncbq1nASpiEHLULBqORZj3FhehgvpmwYLZGCEbEb5gAIJosC8kmMHZZmQqwdGoXRXmqEJIkQuZ5HZYJOVUMUlHUbR4x5SwokQjxEL8UVeaxfFj5JeBKX2U5Ll0QoDlZaVYA1cxBWQuRDlvvE2XEd55VUQINH0YxtVjfVqoMCwrCOg1NkTUNimyOR0nZA5Ch0Ve4wAOQhiEV1zKY4STU9LygZ1YBQAIMzOTo2Q4CiqH6iwzDUOQYRgP9zDiXgtSOAIsg6LYCTgtJnEHchCgAKro1BRhuFE+pfpZQ1Nhpxh47dBjhG4J05DQpizao2OMtQsWswAZB9X0-dkryBbpIU4QZ2OglhjNUELmy05q9PHWqGpatF4tgJj0WMm1fnhFhWv4cuYvKN5ksbVkdN5HLm0K-TSsG0zatxQlzBTfG4wAEQAO4NAYYB0Cto2-J1LtY25LszOQgfGzJMt5IRAlgC7-inOQIRgK4ASJ0wxDEOq3u+2BoUQi7sTxNqI7227EecVquIwUZkTQ6AIAECAKsAMo4HA6DYPgb0QQg2nxLUOgAPoCKQ-iMOEtohMKxAj2PE9gFPBjCrUc-j5PrTL9DyVgDA-dWIPT68AAcvPG92lvVhkPYp-r4vm-6CvjiZ7fC9L4-0PvEapDsKIe8-IEFGHFWAIAUDAPGEQ3D6lXqPO+LtYYv3noHAew9YEL3gToI+r9kFXzXug6+J8kGeVBF-XgERXqkLAOISiqMNyAMVMA0Bu8IFQIHng8I8Dn7EGwXIFB7C46Hxvkg3huC0EcOIKIIR49kExFrqQ8hYBm7A1cNsPAzcrqfW+j4bIgUCGvw4QnSgydU6GPIBnLOQgc7CVWvnF2TxYhGCugQPQ-BmC1FIIQFKCBCA2DhrwPu+pHAKmYOEBA4kXEsHcZ4sA3jfEtD3oE4J4QYDiUoR4uJ-jf6xNEH4-+yMGGbTYNkvxTDinxJYYklg4RXZBJYOHH+f85jEKoPIihq4QShJ8TklofcfiVJCWhNYg9+EuwABKkBRAXERhRZ5iLjnRUQvBXE4MKDAs+cdxmTOGos5Z8Q4ggUoeITpGS8npO6Zk0QZTeAwFZKQchBAv6iCztUCR+g3DiHucAAAVIMuOtTmAu3CPqKwGCsFII4Zs5gUzXguz0eC+ZOy6nTJBQg7h8KxkTKhdspZdS9meTAF84ADz2mkAQPoUgehjnnN6SCLpJSsl0vifeB2z5EgfJeI855ry3CkvJXoT5Pz9Qu3+YC35KLUHoshdCtYsK8GipdgsnFALkUCLlRCzFtFFW7KsPsglRKCAGsNUapuDdTWgAIEAA)

Comment: Excellent! Works as expected, thank you from the bottom from my hearth!
But I think the error handling isn't working as you expected; as you can see in the playground error logs we get `[...] Property 'errMsg' is missing in type [...]`

Comment: It is working as expected, it’s just ugly. You have to divine that “errMsg is missing and required in type {errMsg: {someProp: “misspelled or missing prop” }” actually *means* “your mapping has misspelled or is missing the property “someProp” ”.  There’s no official support for custom error messages in TS, so this is a workaround

Comment: I see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

here is js version

```js
function createObjectConverter(mp) {
  function equals(a, b) {
    return a.length === b.length && a.every((v, i) => v === b[i]);
  }
  function reverseMap(mapping) {
    return Object.entries(mapping).reduce((reversed, [sourceKey, targetKey]) => {
      if (typeof targetKey === 'object' && !Array.isArray(targetKey)) {
        reversed[sourceKey] = reverseMap(targetKey);
      } else if (typeof targetKey === 'object' && Array.isArray(targetKey)) {
        reversed[sourceKey] = targetKey;
      } else {
        reversed[targetKey] = sourceKey;
      }
      return reversed;
    }, {});
  }
  return function convertObject(object, map = mp) {
    const isReversed = !equals(Object.keys(object), Object.keys(map));
    const m = isReversed ? reverseMap(map) : map;
    return Object.entries(m).reduce((newObject, [key, value]) => {
      if (typeof object[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(object[key])) {
        newObject[key] = convertObject(object[key], value);
      } else if (typeof object[key] === 'object' && Array.isArray(object[key])) {
        newObject[key] = object[key];
      } else {
        newObject[value] = object[key];
      }
      return newObject;
    }, {});
  };
}

const convert = createObjectConverter({
  name: 'full_name',
  contact: {
    email: 'user_email',
    phone: 'user_phone',
  },
  azat: 'is_azat',
  array: [],
});

const originalObject = {
  name: 'John',
  contact: {
    email: 'john@example.com',
    phone: '555-123-4567',
  },
  azat: false,
  array: ['1', 3],
};

const convertedObject = convert(originalObject);
console.log(convertedObject);//= { array: [ '1', 3 ], contact: { user_email: 'john@example.com', user_phone: '555-123-4567' }, full_name: 'John',is_azat: false }
const reverseConvertedObject = convert(convertedObject);
console.log(reverseConvertedObject);//= { array: [ '1', 3 ], azat: false, contact: { email: 'john@example.com', phone: '555-123-4567' },name: 'John' }
```