# How to create a function type which takes generic as parameter and has a return type dependent on the properties of the parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Sorry for the long and confusing title, but I'm not sure exactly how to describe whats necessary in a way that would facilitate a shorter one.

Basically what I want to do is create a type such as `func<T>(filterProps:T): SomeReturnType` where `SomeReturnType` is a new type created as a subtype of T but with only fields that are present in the supplied `filterProps` parameter.

For Example

```
interface User {
  name: String
  age: Number
  jobTitle: String
}

const user = find<User>({ name: true, age: true }) {
    // return Type should be inferred to { name: string, age: number }
}

user.name // no error
user.jobTitle // should display error
```

Comment: You really need two generic type parameters for this to possibly work, but unfortunately TypeScript doesn't support *partial* type parameter inference.  The workarounds involve either currying or dummy parameters, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/VNVE7w).  As such this is sort of like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic) (and some others), with the difference that you haven't gotten to the "I need multiple type parameters" part yet.

Comment: @jcalz Awesome! The types you defined in the playground link look super promising. I'll have to spend some time wrapping my feeble mind around them lol. If you want to provide an official answer to the question, I'd be happy to accept it once I've got a full understanding of exactly how these 2 concepts work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below. You need to declare a type that will omit the props you don't need and that type should be the return type of your function

```
interface User {
  name: String
  age: Number
  jobTitle: String
}
type UserWithoutjobTitle = Omit<User, "jobTitle">;


const user = find<User>({ name: true, age: true }):UserWithoutjobTitle =>{
    // return Type should be inferred to { name: string, age: number }
}
```

Here is the updated solution.

```
function find<T ,K>(): Omit<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof K>>
 { 
     return {"name":'test' } as unknown as Omit<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof K>>
};
const user = find<User,{ name: true, age: true }>();
console.log(user.name);
```

Comment: While that works, I'm looking for a solution where the type is inferred or created from the generic type parameter and constrained automatically based on the provided properties of the function parameter.

Comment: I updated another solution, hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function find<T, K extends keyof T>(thing: T, filterProps: K[]) {
  return thing as Pick<T, K>;
}

const ourUser: User = { name: 'John McClane', age: 44, jobTitle: 'Cop' };
const filteredUser = find(ourUser, ['name', 'age']); // Pick<User, "name" | "age">
filteredUser.name; // String
filteredUser.age; // Number
filteredUser.jobTitle; //error
```

Perhaps your version would "find" the `thing` from within the function body, rather than have it passed it as an argument.