# Typescript generics type inferring

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am playing with typescript by implementing a strongly typed rest request mechanism.

Let the code speak:

With this type I want to define the mapping between the routes and the related type of objects:

```
export interface RoutesMapping {
    api1: {
        users: UserApiModel
        products: ProductApiModel,
    }
    api2: {
        "other-route": OtherModel1,
        "another-one-route": OtherModel2
    }
}

export type ApiScope = keyof RoutesMapping
```

The following function is the one I am willing to use to make POST requests

```
export type RestApiPostResponse<T = any> = {
    result: boolean
    data: T
}

export function restPost<S extends keyof RoutesMapping = "api1", T extends keyof RoutesMapping[S] = keyof RoutesMapping[S]>(
  route: T,
  // nervermind this object, is out of scope for the question
  options: ApiRequestOptions<S, any> = {}
): Promise<RestApiPostResponse<RoutesMapping[S][T]>> {
  const url = apiUtils.buildUrl(route as string, options)
  const { payload, headers, isProtected } = options
  return post({
    url,
    isProtected,
    payload,
    headers
  });
}
```

I expect to call this function in the following way

```
const data = await restPost("users")
```

An make typescript infer the return type by inferring it by the scope and the route.

Actually, using it with the default type parameters, it works:

[image]

The problem is when I when I want to call the other api in this way:

```
const data = await restPost<"api2">("other-route")
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and it infers all the possible types

[image]

The only way to solve the problem is to explicitly add the second type parameter

[image]

How can I use all of this without needing to add the second type parameter in the second scenario?

Here is a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-lTRFglBRNOMIBAKGJeA7iWoYBgODm9DHjIilLwKt1eHAyzBk1wsx64KAJLxSFg4AGgyGMSqI-jgvZ9YR9tKBXA85PgNPZ-Pg6Hl7jVwIANoegC69mPi7DK6j15vhYAFA7lRI2zq4D6uh6LAAH42DoJQoHcTxggFMAMEQCgIAwdgC30ABKDgSggJwCGzNMuGsEcYHwjM8Kfc8X1vS8czfYtGDgB0AHpGIAARgLAFQIfhDVEL9gBgCCB0gLh33okkIPcf9On7ECADoJL-Yk4IQpD2AAmTgNk5TEOQh1dDQgBuDsGGwRBezgbte0AgdsRgfZ3zQsTvUzeBmwwfMAHdXHgIciPfaUaSmLBpTQ4zGIAKnC4VwrgAAJABRNF4rgABJcccwS4o0XWNAABl4qIVKAHJCpzNEAE0UoiABxXd1jgAAxFKAA1osYkysDMoQLJ7PsegQBNvgcsTmLgT5UBSuAvN4VzxHc34YAgOBJjgPhESmURSFJWcbT2Q4PIIbYLTgXhgEkNdFs4FAhAIRFEAQHZOGAZytreB1nK4OA3N+WgMC8w7BwTIisw3AhvmlD9ZXlKBzRVELjIYIA)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Woq6aN) which demonstrates your issue and where no other issue (e.g., undeclared types or values) is present.  Relatedly, [images of code or errors are not as helpful as you might think](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); for me, if I can't copy and paste it into my IDE, it's not something I can easily use to diagnose or suggest a solution to a problem.  Good luck!

Comment: I added in the end the link to the playground @jcalz

Comment: Your playground link doesn't work

Comment: @ritaj I updated the link with a slightly changed version: the playground is not meant to be ran, the problem is 100% of type checking, in the the last code lines there is a comment explaining what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Not sure if it is an option for you, but you can avoid the issue by passing the `S` argument as a dummy parameter, so the call would be `await restPost("api2", "other-route")` and both `S` & `T` will get inferred correctly.

Comment: Hello @Oblosys, thank for your suggestion, I will keep it as last option, my goal is to have the syntax as cleanest as possible

Comment: @Apperside thanks... look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic) and its answer and see if it addresses your issue.   There is no partial type parameter inference in TS; the workarounds I know of are currying and dummy parameters, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/w26bzw).

Comment: @Apperside Did the solution end up working, or was there some kind of problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you infer the api-key type parameter, you can actually construct a solution that does what you want:

```
type Model<Route> = // Returns the model value for key Route in RoutesMapping
  keyof RoutesMapping extends infer Api
  ? Api extends keyof RoutesMapping 
    ? Route extends keyof RoutesMapping[Api]
      ? RoutesMapping[Api][Route]
      : never
    : never
  : never

type Routes<Api> = Api extends {} ? keyof Api  : never // Helper to distribute keyof over a union of objects
type AllRoutes = Routes<RoutesMapping[keyof RoutesMapping]> // Union of all route keys: 'users' | 'products' | 'other-route' | 'another-one-route'

export function restPost<Route extends AllRoutes>(
  route: Route,
  options?:{url:string,payload:any}
): Promise<RestApiPostResponse<Model<Route>>> {
 ..
}
```

When applied to a route string, the correct return type for `restPost` is inferred, without needing to specify any type parameters:

```
const data = await restPost("users") // data: RestApiPostResponse<UserApiModel>
const data2 = await restPost("other-route") // data2: RestApiPostResponse<OtherModel1>
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-lTRFglBRNOMIBAKGJeA7iWoYBgODm9Nk43ssxiVcXaAB6AfxmBKKCZhA7OBORZwAEXOCI6BwAOIUMquB8dfY3H4-rE1fB7fh3dRuCgCS8UhYTe8RFTODWB0AfkfhHPIEv15XgaPvZ3kbBHAjZwK+-6oBewBXjeh4huBEZ7gIADa1gALogcSYFhghUYoYQqFIeB6FShwvDAMcUwgaR5GUcS1EUdMDBxvBWbWP2b4EB+X43nQCSvrBHF0XAZEMXAQ5wAAEpQKBQAgEBwKQBCeAQ4wbgJECiRgcBKLw3S8HAR4QOMABWwAckxpiPhQFDwfYLHwaewRIQJDmAQIqHFuJZi6T0BkhmcVDKhIP6IJyADkNJTFgYVwAAPnAYVsjyHIxfFYVGoqQXAKlCUGhlUAmmR5oqmFMbGIiOkVHpcBljAyZcD2YZcVB364NZ8GFgAFA6WUcOBOoGZ0elYM+bB0GO7jKQIApgBgiAUBAGDsAW+gAJQcCUEBOEpwA9gm1j1TAaZYBm2bduBhaXUSDpDgAAjAWAKgQ-CGqIPXAKO45wJAXCdYw1JQO4g1dD0I0AHQTQNxKzfNi3sD6IOZs+YMwwtS0Oroq0ANwdgw2CILwQiLpViMIAm+ydat-1wN6mbwM2Wm0BgADurjwLVh2ddKkVQFg0qrWJw4M31+2EIdx2nbtDJWPylCFrjA4AFSK8KiuSQAomi6twAAkh6cA5hJ2tFGi6xoAAMurRC62F1s5miACaOsRAA4gb6xwAAYjrAAaqsDnjWAE0TFWE6T2IwN8lPU+JnyoDrcCs7w9PiFpvwwPJky3veUCiKQpI3jaeyHMzBDbBawnAJIQEZ5wKBCAQiJrvKnBmT0+dvA6tNcApqe-EzrNlzVCac7K8oFVl-OC73LYSsdibi+moO7UXWry86DBAA)

Note that this assumes the route keys are unique, which seems to be the case since the api key is not passed to `restPost`. I'm also not certain it is wise to introduce all this complexity, but at least it is possible.