# Function which sets a Key/Value where key is a literal (rather than just a string)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want my simple `KV` function to produce an object with a *key* being a literal type and not widened to *string*:

```
function KV<K extends Readonly<string>, V extends any>(key: K, value: V) {
  return { [key as K]: value };
}

type Target = {foo: number};
const t: Target = KV("foo", 43);

type Target2 = { bar: (bar: string) => {bar: string}};
const t2: Target2 = KV("bar", (bar: string) => ({ bar }));
```

Unfortunately, while the generic `K` *is* defined as a literal, I can't find a way to force the returned key-value pair to recognize the key as a literal.

[image]

I have a feeling to get this to work I need to be more explicit about the return type so I tried the KV function like so:

```
function KV2<O extends object, K extends Readonly<string> & keyof O, V extends any, KV extends O & [K: V]>(key: K, value: V): KV {
  return { [key as K]: value } as KV;
}
```

My hopes were high but unfortunately no bacon.

[image]

I've since tried several more variants but have not gotten this to work. Anyone more skilled in the dark arts of literal types have any ideas?

> Code can be found in this [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL9n4W)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think i've answered my question, so I'll post my answer here but if there a better solution I'm open to that and will keep this open for another day before closing:

**Solution:**

```
export function KV<
  K extends string, 
  V extends any, 
  O extends Record<K, V>
>(key: K, value: V): O {
  return { [key as K]: value } as O;
}
```

This then allows me to compose key values and when I merge them together the full typing is preserved because the key's are literal types. So in this example:

```
const kv = KV("foo", 43);
const kv2 = KV("bar", (bar: string) => ({ bar }));

const both = { ...kv, ...kv2 };
```

The type `both` has all the type information of `kv` and `kv2` preserved.

---

Based on helpful feedback from @jcalz I've adjusted my solution in two ways. First off, the implementation above has been simplified to:

```
export function KV<V extends any, K extends string>(key: K, value: V) {
  return { [key]: value } as Record<K, V>;
}
```

This will infer both the *key* and *value* and is a nice compact signature. If, however, you wanted to constrain the *value* to a more narrow definition this will not work because it will then require both generics be stated. This can be avoided by separating the construction with a function and so I introduced `KV2` for this use case:

```
export const KV2 = <V extends any>() => <K extends string>(key: K, value: V) => {
  return { [key]: value } as Record<K, V>;
};
```

This will allow you -- as a for instance -- to accept key values where the value is a string that must start with "kv-is-great":

```
const kv = 
KV2<`kv-is-great${string}`>()("foo", "kv-is-great-or-is-it?");
```

By itself this may not seem very useful but in a larger composition being able to constrain *value* should be a helpful addition that comes at the expense of a slightly more awkward API.

Comment: Your `O` isn't really doing anything; there's no inference site for it so it will just default to the constraint; you might as well use `Record<K, V>` instead of `O`, and `[key as K]` is also not doing anything (`key` is already of type `K`).  You can shorten your answer to [this](https://tsplay.dev/weeoBw).

Comment: @jcalz am I right in saying that if you set the generic `V` you then can no longer infer `K`? I had hoped to be able to shape the value of `V. I supposed I can get this if separate them with a function.

Comment: Right, there is currently no *partial type parameter inference* in TypeScript.  See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic) for more info

Comment: Cool thanks. I've updated my answer based on your feedback @jcalz