# Generics can't be mixed internally and externally?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Doc {
  properties: {
    propA: string,
    propB: number
  }
  //...
}
type Options<TProperty> = {
  properties: TProperty
}

//imagine  
function configDoc<TDoc extends Doc, TProperty extends Partial< TDoc['properties']>>(options: Options<TProperty>): TProperty { return options['properties'] }
```

I want to introduce an external generic as above to constrain the inner generic and return the inner generic . But the result was not what was expected

```
const propA = configDoc<Doc>({properties:{propA:'str' as const}}) // expect  type propA = {propA:'str}
const propB = configDoc<Doc>({properties:{propB:100 as const}}) // expect  type propB = {propA:100}
```

Doc place error .    Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.

The only way I can think of is.

```
function configDocWarpper<TDoc extends Doc,> (){
      return  function _configDoc<TProperty extends Partial< TDoc['properties']>>(options: Options<TProperty>): TProperty{return options['properties']}
}
const propAA = configDocWarpper<Doc>()({properties:{propA:'str' as const}}) // expect  ok  type propAA = {propA:'str}
const propBB = configDocWarpper<Doc>()({properties:{propB:100 as const}}) // expect  ok  type propBB = {propA:100}
```

But this is ugly  Is there another way???

[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=115&pln=26&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsHIN4ChnIAOU6h0YwEAzgFw74FEmECCdVYUoA5gDQMFipAEJ0QAVwC2AI2gMAvgwD0SgHTrcisAE8yyAPKEK6EFQA8AFQAKzctoB8yALz1BtqBWp1r7nZty4KsCScNygKMi4MOIgCMYgyAgmMMDcGAiW6cgQAB6QIAAmVGiYvMg+pHbZeRCFxVZwHsBwADZm5ekA2gDkQmRN1N0Auvb2ABSk8bQGRsAm5hX9OvYAlN42lR7aOMhQEGDiUAmTc6Y9feSUVMPIioFK0CRQBADqABb7H8-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)

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378737/2887218) to the linked question; there is no "partial type argument inference" (as requested in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242 ) so the workarounds are currying (like you're doing) or passing a dummy parameter, both of which are "ugly", unfortunately.  Note that it's less ugly to do something like `const cdw = configDocWarpper<Doc>();` and then later `cdw({properties:{propA:'str' as const}})` and `cdw({properties:{propB:100 as const}})` so that you are reusing the intermediate function.