# Generic function ensuring the type of a given value matches the type defined a Record for the given key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Please let me know if this is a duplicate, but I can't find an answer to this. Maybe because I'm missing the right words to search for as you can see in the title :/

Is it possible to define a generic function in TypeScript that receives two arguments (a key and a value) and verifies that the type of the given value matches the type defined in a Record type depending on the given key? This may sound confusing. Let me give you a simple example:

```js
import { setAttribute } from './attribute_helper'

type Human = {
  name: (name: string) => void
  age: (age: number) => void
}

function setName(name: string): void {
  // ...
}

setAttribute<Human>('name', setName) // valid
setAttribute<Human>('age', setName) // invalid

// should work with a different Record type:
setAttribute<Cat>('food', giveFood)
```

Here's how this would work if one specific Record type can be used in the definition of the function:

```js
type Human = {
  name: (name: string) => void
}

function setAttribute<T extends keyof Human>(key: T, value: Human[T]): void {
}

function setName(name: string): void {
  // ...
}

setAttribute('name', setName)
```

But in my case, `setAttribute` is imported from a different file and needs to work with different Record types it doesn't know about at definition time. It needs to be typed when it is called.

Here's a sketch which unfortunately is not valid TypeScript, but it may help to illustrate the problem:

```js
// attribute_helper.ts
export function setAttribute<T>(key: keyof T as V, value: V): void {
}
```

Comment: I think [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w11ZKw) is the closest you can get; your function wants to be generic in both `T` and `K extends keyof T`, and you want the compiler to infer `K` while you manually specify `T`.  But TS doesn't have such partial type parameter inference.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378737/2887218 for more information.  If you have control over `setAttribute` I'd probably prefer the curried version to the dummied version.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer.

Comment: Nice! I actually tried currying but could not get it right. Thank you so much. Please write up an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Note that there is [a `Record<K, V> utility type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) in global scope so a type named `Record` is not advisable.  I'd suggest some other name, especially in SO example code (where people searching for `Record` are looking for something else)

Comment: Good advice. I'll change the example. The code is just a simplified version of what I tried to achieve. I'm not actually calling types Record :) Was just trying to make clear it's a Record type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, what you want is a function like

```
function setAttribute<T, K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): void { }
```

which is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) both in the type of the record ou'd call it like

```
setAttribute<MyRecord>('name', setName); // want it to be okay, but error!
```

Unfortunately, this is not valid TypeScript.  You can't manually specify some generic parameters (like putting `MyRecord` in for `T` in this case) and have the compiler infer the rest of them (like inferring `"name"` for `K` in this case).  That would require *partial type parameter inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Right now it's not possible.

It might be tempting to try to use [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to get this behavior, like

```
function setAttribute<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): void { }
```

but while this does let `setAttribute<MyRecord>('name', setName)` compile, it does not work the way you want; the `K` type parameter will not be inferred from `key`; instead it will simply use the default, which is `keyof T` in this case, which is not what you want.  You want `K` to be `"name"` so that the compiler could accept `setName` but reject `setAge` for the second parameter.

So right now this is not possible.  A single generic function requires callers to either manually specify all its type parameters, or let the compiler infer all its type parameters.

---

The workarounds I know of are either to pass in a dummy parameter of type `T` so that the compiler can infer both `T` and `K`:

```
function setAttributeDummy<T, K extends keyof T>(dummyT: T, key: K, value: T[K]): void { }

const dummyRecord: MyRecord = null!;
setAttributeDummy(dummyRecord, 'name', setName) // valid
setAttributeDummy(dummyRecord, 'age', setName) // invalid
```

Or to make a curried function that lets you manually specify `T` and returns *another* function that infers `K`:

```
function setAttributeCurry<T>(): <K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: T[K]) => void {
    return (k, v) => {
        /* your impl here */
    }
}

setAttributeCurry<MyRecord>()('name', setName); // valid
setAttributeCurry<MyRecord>()('age', setName); // invalid
```

This works, but is awkward looking and repetitive.  If you're going to use a curried function you might as well use it just once for any particular value of `T`, like this:

```
const setMyRecordAttribute = setAttributeCurry<MyRecord>();

setMyRecordAttribute('name', setName); // valid
setMyRecordAttribute('age', setName); // invalid
```

And then again for any other value like

```
const setSomeOtherAttribute = setAttributeCurry<{ a: string, b: number }>();
setSomeOtherAttribute('b', 123); // okay
setSomeOtherAttribute('a', 123); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkUgC4CeMyAsmQEoTwD2ATgCZIC8ehxvokALiQAKfhCFQSzAJbAA5gEpOAPiQA3RtNY9eREHPEj9h4AFcwAIwjMlHVRq06kAX3xOAZqeDwS0xsCQoCBIAOXAIUXCJKVlFIQd2Al1iAHoUpAA6LKdXDy8fPwCgkgBBEhiLUxIIABFzMDIAHgAVABokAGkkCAAPauBWKCQAawgyRnckZuVhVnqyZqE2kbGhDva1TFNDZoBtDoBdBXjNRJc3XiZgSSQ5sAb6JjYhGkeWdi4zDAwAQgBuJzFMoVKq1eazeZvNjtADkYhh7WKYUgSjS6kwjl4QPKMkq1Tq9zIEMJUNYsOMCMCwWREFR6Vkmwwjjy3l8-ippRx0jxEAAwqZmMwmtNhMckI0ur1+oMVuNJiLhmsNkt9kcVOpTtxkkRmMEBQFhMMNrZVEltbwUgAqJDjAVIaRgGAYJAAC2syEtKScvFcPouxGxIOq-MFTVeDHeMwUwjh4UpSPCCj+SDRjMxAeCwNxoJDQsa4aerCjMYpiOpieTaIZGO0TiuN2KBfeWe5oM4HJbPNzYboEbYUYBgOCTbYndBMfhZdCFZT6TT2ixw97hbH1RLBnj5ZRlfpwHn-qI9ZIHIAyoxIAB5Ehu5ir5BcQPZ4MCvO4JAgaIyeTtCxCMyWawXAHIcSDPS9r2sO8YwsSkAEYACYAGYk1nJBGGGEAyBAsCICvG8oJhEA4KQlC0WsZgWDcfBnCAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond quickly and for writing up this excellent answer!