# Enforce argument to be a keyof other property that extends (or partially) a type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function called `updateMany` which accepts a generic type of an entity and allows to update certain data based on the entity and a "by" property which should be a keyof `data`. Something like this:

```js
function updateMany<Table>() {
  return <
    Data extends { [column in keyof Table]?: Table[column] },
    By extends keyof Data
  >(params: {
    by: By;
    data: Table[];
  }) => {};
}
```

*(I wrapped the function inside another function since I wasn't sure how to achieve it in a single function)*

Now, everything seems to be working, except the fact that `data` has to have all of the properties. When I try to wrap it inside `Partial`, then I can pass to `by` properties that doesn't exists in `data`. I know that my implementation is incorrect, but this is as far as I could get it to what I want.

### [Play in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=49&pln=21&pc=48#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gWAChlkBBALmRAFcBbAI2gG4iSAhSmh515AYU51GUFoQC%20RIjGogEYYAHsQyagAcAJnEgBZOCCwAeACpx6AGwgA%20ABQBKPLygQw1KMoO8SAES1xkEAA9IEHUAZzxkAG0EBTM6ZVBkAGsILAUYZBNzCABdAH5KLIto2Pic5DEAGk9kNhxA4LDk1PTkHzA4XhtVOCg4WlDKAmISZHosSjrRUeRNDsLTYpzpivsAXks8MVEJQiIAen3kUIALBWozdTGUADc4M2ArgFpZ32QEPWvkHqh5e%20RWkUIEQYiBQmBkAANACMyDWKg0Wggun0BnQ8mwNls1lwYwmyAARKQCZVXvMoriKMhYWJymJbKIDkc7g91CClOCoQAmOEIubIvSGdGYLBYnF4yhEklkuCUSKUyjQ0kcZBc0kCVUVOkMySEQ7IAACYFCT0CqggclNUCgCig-CoCghiTmnUIoM5kIALLy1PyUUKMJi7OLxpK%20NKXXKFdTlZQebTVoy9UcjSazRawFabXavA6ncphdh2WCIZCAMw%20xE6QVowOi4O40OErwR3xRsiK2Oq9VxrWJ3X61OmgLmy3QbNtKgQTAnaDIRKFnB6K6Jdqu92lgCslb9NcXYsb%20IJLdJkYpHZjtTjPeQZdJXko3oT9KYQA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJR6RW) meet your needs?  You do need something like currying [since TS doesn't support partial type parameter inference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218), so I can't really make that much better (except you can write `const updateManyEntities = updateMany<Entity>();` and reuse it), but the rest of it has been improved, I think.  If this works for you I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz This is much better than my implementation since it really enforces what I wanted to achieve, but I'm losing the autocompletion of data.

Comment: Then does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOz6lW) work better?  Check your use cases and get back to me.

Comment: @jcalz it looks like `updateManyEntities({ by: "C", data: [{ A: 1, B: 2 }] });` is working, which shouldn't. Since "C" is not in data

Comment: I've updated @jcalz answer to [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnX1dW), which seems to meet all your goals. I've also included a version which doesn't return a function.

Comment: @ArnovanLiere thanks, but your implementation allows me to pass properties that don't exist in Entity, which we don't want to happen

Comment: @EliyaCohen ugh, sorry about that.  Try [this version](https://tsplay.dev/N7KZnN) then.  Let me know

Comment: @jcalz perfection. can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I will when I get a chance (on mobile now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here would be to write `updateMany()` like this:

```
function updateMany<T>() {
  return <
    K extends keyof T,
    P extends K
  >(params: {
    by: P;
    data: (Pick<T, K> & Partial<T>)[];
  }) => { };
}
```

Both my version and yours use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to work around the lack of "partial type parameter inference" (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)), since there's no way to call a function with multiple type parameters like `T`, `K`, and `P` and have the caller manually specify `T` while letting the compiler infer `K` and `P`.  Currently in TypeScript it's all or nothing; you can either manually specify all three, or let the compiler infer all three.  Currying sidesteps this by having one function where you specify `T` return another function where the compiler infers `K` and `P`.

Anyway, `K` corresponds to the keys present on the elements of `data`, and `P` corresponds to the key specified in `by`.  I do this with two type parameters instead of just `K` for both, since we *don't* want the compiler to infer that `K` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the key from `by` and the ones in `data`.  Instead we [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `P extends K` so that whatever `K` is inferred from `data`, we require the key in `by` to be in that set.

Conceptually we would have `data` be of type `Pick<T, K>[]` and that would be it.  But since you said you wanted some better [IntelliSense autocompletion](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) for `data`, I've [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `Pick<T, K>` with `Partial<T>`. Luckily the compiler seems to use `Pick<T, K>` to infer `K` to be only those keys actually present in `data` entries, while also using `Partial<T>` to provide hints for autocompletion.

Let's see if it works:

```
const updateManyEntities = updateMany<Entity>();;

const X1 = updateManyEntities({ by: "A", data: [{ A: 1 }] }); // okay
const X2 = updateManyEntities({ by: "A", data: [{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 2 }] }); // okay
const X4 = updateManyEntities({ by: "C", data: [{ A: 1, B: 2 }] }); // error!
// ---------------------------> ~~
// Type '"C"' is not assignable to type '"A" | "B"'
const X3 = updateManyEntities({ by: "D", data: [{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 2 }] }); // error!
// ---------------------------> ~~
// Type '"D"' is not assignable to type '"A" | "B" | "C"'
const X5 = updateManyEntities({ by: "D", data: [{ A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4 }] }); // error!
// ---------------------------> ~~                            ----> ~~~~
// Type '"D"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Entity'        |
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'D' does not exist in type...
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-3IYABEAKDZwPx+YAAcxAcHofRQYAUyGwfuQgfByAAPgy2MHJS8AMxyrY6RUYf604EMgAiGpZWrhHK5lF5-E7gqNotN5qtXuQLtHY4d7s9hBNPqzgabIbDVEjyGjsYTSZTGfTmYDjPzhZBB6D-pLRIArBXvtWDtSASrQU3IS2YW2ER2eXzKKWWg3KLLDWFftoEHa1p0xcdINdZAPQqOD4IQ+DHUnD1h1nPcF1DcMVzXeNE2TVMd19ANglCcI-iwEMELzYcAHl6AAKwgORkD6TBoH6ZBaFxLEQD6HA-D9BBgBgHBAgjAB3ZRVHNP0oH+Fo9HUbMGxDdQFCOZcNi8MMNlADNiIAOmMyRCCAA)