# Enforce interface for array of objects and also create type from a mapped value

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript to make sure queues fulfill the `IQueue` interface:

```
export interface IQueue {
  id: string;
  handler: () => void;
}

const queues:IQueue[] = [
  { id: 'a', handler: () => { } },
  { id: 'b' }, // handler is missing, should be an error
];
```

I also want a `QueueId` type which is a union of all the ids:

```
const queues = [
  { id: 'a', handler: () => { } },
  { id: 'b' },
] as const;


export declare type QueueId = (typeof queues[number])['id'];

export const start = (queueId:QueueId) => {
  ...
};

start('z'); // should be a typescript error
```

But I can't get them to work together. The `QueueId` type requires an `as const` type. Several posts recommend doing a noop cast but I get the `readonly cannot be assigned to the mutable type...` error. So I tried making it writeable but it gives an "insufficient overlap" error:

```
type DeepWriteable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepWriteable<T[P]> };
(queues as DeepWriteable<typeof queues>) as IQueue[];
```

Is it possible to do both?

Here's a full example:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICSBFArjfdAb1HXTABMAudAZyjkgHMBuU9ACyQgoBt4aACgCU6ALwA%20dADcA9pTYgAvqFApZEeugCO%20fLXHoA2uxIgyZSjQDkAD2sAadmS49%20cIaMnF0Sp%20d9-MjMLcmp0awBPR2d0AHo49CgOMANaDllcXgp0ACMMbnR4OFk4dEFXPnhyAzgYXTA6imF2P1AAXXQkA3VNKEVQChgUXiQ6pMiABww8AhhMHLFyqCmYWQQdPRhaIwhcAFt8uHbhI2tKa3aBkASk7agkjhmthYnptQ0tWHpZ-AWqX7zRYRABe1mutwAyhkAO5FOAlMpgDbcSKbOboCiybYQawPBBZXhosD7Sb8fYwaBYQGgFbTdAAERgMEmAHVGLAkLl%20AAeAAqUiWRHQAFo6kgsRAicYAArkCDoADWMEi63QfPaNCZLPZYE53Jg-KMMvaUiUikEujmBm6jOZbI5MC5vLpaw2Vv0ElEtpwWyMV1UN0SADlZA9aLhJpNSrAcho3tsUIxJlBRhAmAA6UpMBx5XAPGC2aNwB7JDAe7agW6F4sPIbILIPCs2gy%20ub%20xRAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZr9Em) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wow, yeah - amazing. And here I thought I was getting good at typescript.  I'll have to study the asQueues magic

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer explaining it when I get a chance.

Comment: I opted for a more general approach that strays less from what you were doing.  If you really want me to write up how `asQueues()` works I can (but maybe not today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want the compiler to infer string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for the `id` properties without inferring [a `readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) for `queues`, then you can move the [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) from the `queues` initializer to just the `id` properties in question:

```
const queues = [
  {
    id: 'x' as const,
    handler: () => { },
  },
  {
    id: 'y' as const,
    handler: () => { },
  },
];

/* const queues: ({
     id: "x";
     handler: () => void;
   } | {
     id: "y";
     handler: () => void;
   })[] */

type QueueId = (typeof queues[number])['id'];
// type QueueId = "x" | "y"
```

---

At this point you want to check that `queues`'s type is assignable to `IQueue[]` without actually actually [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as `IQueue[]`, since that would make the compiler forget about `"x"` and `"y"` entirely.

TypeScript doesn't currently have a built-in type operator to do this; there is a feature request for one (tentatively) called `satisfies` at [microsoft/TypeScript#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) where you would maybe write something like

```
// this is not valid TS4.6-, don't try it:
const queues = ([
  {
    id: 'x' as const,
    handler: () => { },
  },
  {
    id: 'y' as const,
    handler: () => { },
  },
]) satisfies IQueue[];
```

And then the compiler would complain if you left out a `handler` or something.  But there is no `satisfies` operator.

Luckily you can essentially write a helper function which (if you squint at it) behaves like a `satisfies` operator.  Instead of writing `x satisfies T`, you'd write `satisfies<T>()(x)`.  Here's how you write it:

```
const satisfies = <T,>() => <U extends T>(u: U) => u;
```

That extra `()` in there is because `satisfies` is a *curried function* in order to allow you to specify `T` manually while having the compiler infer `U`.  See [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218) for more information.

Anyway, when we use it, we can see that it will complain if you mess up:

```
const badQueues = satisfies<IQueue[]>()([
  {
    id: 'x' as const,
    handler: () => { },
  },
  { id: 'y' as const }, // error!
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Property 'handler' is missing
]);
```

And when you don't mess up, it doesn't forget about `'x'` and `'y'`:

```
const queues = satisfies<IQueue[]>()([
  {
    id: 'x' as const,
    handler: () => { },
  },
  {
    id: 'y' as const,
    handler: () => { },
  },
]);

/* const queues: ({
     id: "x";
     handler: () => void;
   } | {
     id: "y";
     handler: () => void;
   })[]
*/

type QueueId = (typeof queues[number])['id'];
// type QueueId = "x" | "y"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJKiSwLICyA9gG4QDCtwUALgIJRQQBO7AJas8JUknisOSAI4BXCAqhIAvEgDaY8aMLbtggCYAuJAHIAHqaQhlktuwA0WvQAsQwAxn4mAFAEpVAD48JABfJ109cOdSAki9JEMTUwBPKxsJKUcY8TcPLz5fAJVg3DCIhOj4pABdAG5nAHoAKkz7WQUlXziE8SSkACJzAYbq13dPbyR-IKR6WkNR3tCkAB8dXtJ+gZSRnNyJgqLZ+cX90L91GqRmxqJndhSYZABFTogASQNVacfn2gAZh1FNB1MA5GAAEb8GqXUyGUz1JqNJB-V7vL4-IYDNaDXb3SKhAmkcjQOCIJAAZRAQigAME0A2fWA7H4AKoSA+bxBTP0xiQHD4gmAAHMluN8lMZiU5gsDOLSETiNU7NIoDTBHSGco1AAeAAqDkC0uCuoAqkgIOZWR5lPrjXITGbisE5KNieJVewkJCQAZuUofurafToLque8rsa-D5NGNeXp+hZ0rYshVenlJoVpi6QlVKuntGUk2lrKn2uEkI0Ufw+LQ+ABCHLVpAAP3bHc7XfbSF1AFo+0gAAp154CFJmTMFKyapBgTVQYUi5yw93K7Re4GBtTBzWhqDhgMQKP+WM5Hq9JOWMttDiFiVZ44ysr5qL32L7RL81Ip2-ZeOkFOUq5i+77lCufhrtoLR-lu0DdJ+X4mNiCoJEB2YmrKZwASs6wXpe-I7HsAGAYcwEnHKqHiBcVzOLcHqkGiSBHpiag+GigJwVAYIQtCfCwuo8IGIiqEtkxLHfGo2K4kRBJiEqYikpQFIAPLsC4-AAGKCOYOjOMKrJ8OyFIRiCuoANKWtaEC2gK7BCqKQb2UupQ5P05lUUg6FPsEpzys4CkqlkZZHjqvaWVaNoGMogpLie8gglAJhxgkAB06VlOoHyJMASAANYQCknHmTUJimQouoAKLWnwCDsBZWU1A4dkOSKgTBEq2iwrMCVKFBnrBb1jJqDYoVnvGxbfiApjNd5OazC+4ETUhZiQlYlYtrW9ZNvGLbdj2-aDiOtBjo8k5kXwM7KPOPBLhBokopuQ1JRo5UQLqAwgAMgTNW9H2Qt9NQMaiTzoiCrG-KDnHPTxUIwnCCJItUYmg8xGKSYMX0yQD8lyYQoRAA)