# Typescript doesn't return object keys after passing one of generic types

Tags: typescript, material-ui

For code:

```js
type PropsOrVoid<T> = T extends Record<string, unknown> ? T : void;
const makeSxRecordsTry = <
  Props = void,
  ClassKeys extends string = string,
>(createStyles: (theme: Theme, props: PropsOrVoid<Props>) => Record<ClassKeys, StyleObj>) => (props: PropsOrVoid<Props>) => createStyles(systemTheme, props ?? {});

const result = makeSxRecordsTry(() => ({
  root1: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  root2: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  root3: {
    color: 'red',
  }
}))();
const resultKeys: keyof typeof result = 'root';
```

`resultKeys` are recognized properly as `'root1' | 'root2' | 'root3'` but things get messy when I try to provide a type for Props:

```js
const resultWithProps = makeSxRecordsTry<{ color: string }>(() => ({
  root1: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  root2: {
    color: 'red',
  },
  root3: {
    color: 'red',
  }
}))({ color: 'blue' });

const resultWithPropsKeys: keyof typeof resultWithProps = 'root';
```

Expected behavior is to see `'root1' | 'root2' | 'root3'`, just like in previous example. Instead, `resultWithPropsKeys` is of type `string`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQJ4GcYFMTJqgGywHkAjAKywGN4BfOAMyghDgHIABEAV2AHp0GbCDYBuAFDiqEAHaY4gzDgAqACxxY4AXkTi4+uGCigAhlFQAuXQYMgTwGVbYBiAIwAhABwBhAGLu2ABo9GzgCYABzVRgnZwBBXwARADZfAFEgkP1aYJt0alkAEzNLa1C7B1jXABYATl846szQsMjo2PdXRLTE32aDHPFaCXF8ME01DW04MawIBgUhFXUQLAlZlHwiMnJptCVcLZIKahgAHknVgD511HG4AAVmMHRiKAA1CGBCi6vp5TgWAAHtgZIV0HAAEoFKA-TDGGQRQJwbgyADWMggAHcZH8APxwAFWABuX0KI2kcngdjRWGQQOh0lh6GU5mmZxCTwgL2mpO+uTg3gIJnQ6AA0lgMICQVgwRD4Q4ItMFYjglcABRUKBYEzYPCELDoKzqmArLBWS5YZFGblGx7PV4fMlnLkvK4ASm0f0Z0B+QpF4sl6GR+u2FA9Xrg6ptLysrsdn2+LodEa0fy1Or1R3Q6sUwkt1odcDxBIQtHdFNk8m16G4BHgOhpdIZMPBrNQ6vVnrTUYQIWYEBgrisfZs0gI0Cc2sK-UG+gHMAATCOsnBx5P2NPZwKFwBmFdjiATqBTrAzgW0Ibu91dkZ8PhwAAGNbrMAlGEfcDMmm10giMmAAAvM9DGeLAoAIVAvwhR82AXVw2DgAAfTcIEHRdEJQuC0JgXc2E-UhuHgU1FQhCIsGpQ1BDgLF1BkOAAEkZjZGAIFAiBiW+TQTBmO5NAYaB7VtKwpCreAX3rd87VpVB5l48Y5IkhtUMHMRJEpatDVfAB1YBTXjaYm3pH1mXbM4kHXE8FBgBElVoDUu0jdVRzgeCDwMSzT3PEI51cnDlzKfRPM3M9t37HD90Ctcjw3ODQovK8bwsmKrLYUgCG4LBEPLO8HzSIFxhoEDSCwVQTE4wTgAhViFCwTRYPgzCVKXJrsMHPDH2RchuHkcJaTgBxQKwCqeulExwCIAA6RiqR1QpkWfLT610-SHSkz8qrgOSNkfFUIkfSbRKpVylpgFbVHjKSrBk7a+MU07zoMnQ2pgMQgA)

Comment: someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mbA7PN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Playground added. Thanks for sugestion @jcalz :)

Comment: Are you not asking about the error at `props ?? {}`?  If you're not, then can you resolve it?

Comment: [Currying is one way...](https://tsplay.dev/mL4Q4m)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to manually specify one type parameter and have the compiler infer the other; that is unfortunately not possible.  Looks like this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218) and then the various workarounds either look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w16lyN).  Let me know if I've failed to address the issue.