# Type of argument depending on value of other one

Tags: typescript

- The following function admit a generic called `T`.
- The property `key` only admit a string that should be a key of `T`. We will use `Obj` as `T`.
- The property `value` should admit the type of `Obj[key]`. Cant manage to implement it.

```js
const fn = <T>({
  key,
  value
}: {
  key: keyof T;
  // Value type should be the type of the value of the key 'key' of 'T' generic
  value: typeof T[key];
}) => {
  return undefined;
};

type Obj = {
  keyA: {
    propertyFromA: string;
  };
  keyB: {
    propertyFromB: string;
  };
};

fn<Obj>({
  key: "keyA",
  value: { propertyFromB: "string" } // should only admit type { propertyFromA: "string" }, since Im passing 'keyA'
});
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-platform-lusjft?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Aside: I am renaming your types to conform with common TypeScript naming conventions: your `Obj` type will become `T`, to make it obvious that this is a generic type parameter and not a specific type; and, your `obj` type will become `Obj`, to make it obvious that this is a TypeScript type and not a JavaScript value.  I suggest you make the same changes to the code in your question to make it easier for others.)

The type of `value` is something like `T[typeof key]`.  But since you have `typeof key` as being just `keyof T`, then this is `T[keyof T]` and therefore a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all possible property value types from `T`. Since you want the compiler to only allow `value` properties that correspond to the particular *subtype* of `keyof T` the caller uses for `key`, this indicates that you need the type of `key` to be an additional [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof T`.

That gives us:

```
const fn = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>({
  key,
  value
}: {
  key: K;
  value: T[K];
}) => {
  return undefined;
};
```

But unfortunately now you can't call

```
fn<Obj>({ // error!
  key: "keyB",
  value: { propertyFromB: "string" } 
});
```

That's because TypeScript does not have *partial type argument inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218) and its answer for more detailed information.

When you call a generic function, you either need to manually specify all the type parameters, or not specify any of them and let the compiler infer them.  You can't specify one and let the compiler infer the other.  Which is sad, because that's exactly the behavior you want.  For now there are only workarounds.

---

One workaround for this is to use [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to split the generic function into two, so callers can specify the type argument to the first function, which then returns another generic function where callers let the compiler infer the remaining type parameters.  It looks like this:

```
const fn = <T extends object>() => <K extends keyof T>({
  key,
  value
}: {
  key: K;
  value: T[K];
}) => {
  return undefined;
};
```

So now instead of calling `fn<Obj>({...})`, you need to call `fn<Obj>()({...})` (note the extra function call).  If you're going to use `fn<Obj>()` a lot, you can save it to an intermediate function:

```
const fnObj = fn<Obj>();
```

And then use it to get the inference you want:

```
fnObj({
  key: "keyA",
  value: { propertyFromB: "string" } // error
});

fnObj({
  key: "keyB",
  value: { propertyFromB: "string" } // okay
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKjApgDylsAEwhhACMArLYKAPgAoBKZWtAaWzwOJgGssAniDgx0DAN4AoGH0EAaaTABuAQwA2AVyySAvgC4YUmfwEG2AbkWrNWA+gDabALqWdzJKyMwATligbvRA0iLDgASzAsQldLSSgBAAcsGAB5SmRDRRMAQQMvGQTvECTveIAxIoBbXJhobwiAc0sZHWbZAQAhPMUCopLyqq7aqHqwJsVW3VjQSFgENIoMhFQFhkZY+cp6LxMDACIcvYUZay08mELirFKBCpBKob26xr2YHRgAeg-sbyLvXXWkkkmwo2yygn2Jg6Rys6jOhgufWuA3uj2eY1e7y+pF4KgEAMsQA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Its working. One question: TS is complaining about the use of `object`, should I use `Record<string, unknown>` or `unknown`?

Comment: TS does not complain about `object`.  You might be using ESLint's ban-types rule (and ESLint is not TS).  If so, I would disable/ignore the rule for `extends object`.  I really [do not like](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640) that complaint, since the problem is not with `object`, but with other things people try to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really explain why, so this may be a lacking answer, sorry for that (I will update the answer if I found or someone comments). But from my experience, I only managed to make what you want work by using automatic inference from the function arguments.

Type the function without default values for the types, and create the generics for the other fields, like key and value:

```
const fn = <Obj extends {}, K extends keyof Obj, V extends Obj[K]>(o: Obj, key: K, value: V) => {
  return undefined;
};
```

Now you can call the function with the three parameters, and the inference will work as expected:

```
type obj = {
  keyA: {
    propertyFromA: string;
  };
  keyB: {
    propertyFromB: string;
  };
};


fn({} as obj, "keyA", {propertyFromB: 'bar'}); //error
fn({} as obj, "keyA", {propertyFromA: 'foo'}); //success
```

You probably should use a real object instead of this cast: `{} as obj`

Here is a [working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=45&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeA8gIwFYwKYAeUeYAJhDAN4C%20ANDANL5EnkwDWeAniHDFtnoA1ZsTIUBAbQYBdAHwAKEAC5%20Oepy6qG9AG4BDADYBXPKqEBKZHKoAoGDABOeKMceJjZPHACWYPKQA3LbUwbZQXAAOeDAgOMh2DpoAgqqU9g4wkY4g0Y4RAGI5ALapMNCOfgDmwQ6hGZoAQmkZDtm5ePlcRSDFzeVQlWA1GfX1tqCQsOiqcbgo6Zkc3GWtiUuZ7XmFJWUA5MTQyXtrdGtNymuLG205290l-Qd40I0nS9Qhtt8ICuj0ACIUgD6JQtp0dr0npg9tQLMFfjQYPoKHNAcDQeCuj0%20qo9jC4QiwH90SsQVQsZDSnj9LD4bZEdRkaj1DAgWTMXcIQ9evtaYTvkA)

Comment: I don't see the advantage that `V` gives you here.  You definitely need a `K`, though.  Your technique of adding an extra parameter of type `Obj` with no actual value of that type is what I've been calling "dummying", and is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378737/2887218) along with currying as workarounds for the lack of partial type argument inference in TS