# How to infer in TypeScript template parameters

Tags: typescript

I have tree nodes with values in TypeScript defined like this

```
class Node<T> {
  public readonly value: T;

  constructor (value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  // ...
}

class Container<U, N extends Node<T>, T> extends Node<U> {
  private children: N[];

  public getChildrenValues(): T[] {
    return this.children.map((child) => child.value);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to somehow infer the T type in Container? If I instantiate container like this

```
const x = new Container<string, Node<number>, number>();
```

I have to repeat `number` twice. It would be much nicer if I could do just

```
const x = new Container<string, Node<number>>();
```

It seems to me that for the type system it should be obvious that T is now a number. I know I can do something like

```
class Container<U, N extends Node<unknown>> extends Node<U> {
  public getChildrenValues(): (N extends Node<infer T> ? T : never)[] {
    // ...
  }
}
```

but I have more methods like this in the class so I need to repeat this crazy type definition like 5 times in the same class. Is there a simpler approach?

Comment: TS doesn't currently have partial type parameter inference.  I would do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY473m); does that work for you? If so I could write up an answer; if not, could you elaborate on the problem?  Also, note how there are unrelated errors in the code in that link (uninitialized properties, an undeclared `map()` method, etc); could you fix those in your question so that it's not distracting?

Comment: In short, yeah, you need to define `T` somewhere, somehow. The idea that @jcalz posted should more or less solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, your solution looks nice, I will use it. I also wonder if TypeScript will alow the inference in the future or there's some reason this would be difficult to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently have *partial type argument inference* when calling [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions (or [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#generic-classes) constructors), as requested in [micorosoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  You either have to manually specify all the type arguments, or let the compiler infer all of them.  There are workarounds involving [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) or giving dummy arguments, which can be seen in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218).

But in this case you don't really need inference.  You can compute your `T` type explicitly from `N`.  You can do it with `N extends Node<infer T> ? T : never`, with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), or because `Node<T>` has a `value` property of type `T` you can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like `N['value']`.  And you can refactor this computation into its own type function:

```
type T<N extends Node<any>> = N['value'];
```

Armed with that, you can just write `T<N>` wherever you would normally write `T`, and this will work without inference.  It's a *little* more complicated than just `T`, but not much:

```
class Container<U, N extends Node<any>> extends Node<U> {

    private children!: N;

    public getChildrenValues(): T<N>[] {
        return this.children.map((child) => child.value);
    }

}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPksUvBiFFEgHID2AJhADwAqAfHkSdzAK4BGGAJbwkAJwgh6tYBgCeSAG6ZeEAIQAuJCwDcXbsTAgYACnj8tJgB5aQwOQEokAXg53Ht+3iQBffb8JuABc5GGQWJmokCCsgiGB6KjpGJnc2DmcaAG0AcmUMVRyAXT1-MgoqAGEZIJAhYAgxJgBVABoaaNj4xJoGZjSOGLiEpL6WjgJ-HjEhZTjSAAshDHoJYE0aUoMSPkERJABzCCDKpZW1gDUVaBMHLQjqNiyizm3tiSDeMWAkIKWoAB08DOq3iAKMpjMIKcrkWy3oAPyqgcejeASmJAA9JikAC8f4-IQfEA)

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. It helped a lot.