# Typescript - Dynamic Generics Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I don't know what exactly to call this problem but this is my case.

I want `defaultValue` to automatically get type based on `id` value.

```
type User = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

type PropConfig<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  id: K;
  label: string;
  defaultValue: T[K];
};

const config: PropConfig<User, 'age'> = {
  id: 'age',
  label: 'Age',
  defaultValue: 18,
};
```

This is what I want:

```
type PropConfig<T, K = keyof T> = {
  id: K;
  label: string;
  defaultValue: T[K]; // Error here
};

const config: PropConfig<User> = {
  id: 'age',
  label: 'Age',
  defaultValue: 18,
};
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have *partial type argument inference* as proposed in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) so there's no way to specify `T` while having the compiler infer `K`, at least not without workarounds involving curried helper functions or dummy parameters (see [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic) for more info).

Luckily, I don't think you want `PropConfig` to *be* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`.  Instead, you want `PropConfig<T>` to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the possible types for each `K` in `keyof T`.  That is, you want to *distribute* the type across unions in `keyof T`.  There are a number of ways to do that, but the one I usually do is to make what's called a *distributive object type*, as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It looks like this:

```
type PropConfig<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: {
  id: K;
  label: string;
  defaultValue: T[K];
} }[keyof T]
```

I immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), producing the following for `PropConfig<User>`:

```
type PropConfigUser = PropConfig<User>;
/* type PropConfigUser = {
    id: "name";
    label: string;
    defaultValue: string;
} | {
    id: "age";
    label: string;
    defaultValue: number;
} */
```

which is the type you want:

```
const config: PropConfig<User> = {
  id: 'age',
  label: 'Age',
  defaultValue: 18,
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgOwEMBbCALijmEQEt8BzAbhz0PvIIFdiAjJZ7AF8BOUJCgAFRAHswAYWn4AZjXoAeACoA+VBigBtANJQ6UANYQQ0pVA0BdALQB+CllwmAJhUMC8AG0I+PwoqWgZfKA8IJUJOP2AANUI-Tg4NIzsBQShBfQsrG3scUXBoKVkFZVV4JF1y+UUVdRrELQEAegAqKDEymQaq+hbdNzw8Gi8oACIiUimI-0CIYMpqOiYWMaiYuMTk1JC18JxsgB8MTfHJqbYIecuoAKDDsI33PG3Y+KSUjnxuPiILJQTrtYrYADGiioUChgwo9UqTTULR0aFGngoAHJbliADSbJ7LbEAQXY+M2n12PwOUAAjAAOAlCARAA)

Comment: This was really helpful, but led to me finding what I think is a bug. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50147