# Typescript avoid generic type redundancy in function call

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a `generic` `abstract` `class` that takes a generic `type` `T`, which is the argument to a function called `test`.

```
abstract class AdvancedMarket<T>{
  abstract test(t: T): void
}
```

I then have a `generic` `class` that extends `AdvancedMarkets` and defines the `test` function.

```
class AMarket1<T> extends AdvancedMarket<T> {
  test(t: T): void {
    console.log(t + ": 1")
  }
}
```

Lastly, I have a `generic` `function` that takes 2 `type` arguments: `V` which is the `type` passed to the `abstract` `class` `AdvancedMarket` , and `T` which is the `type` of the `abstract` `class` `AdvancedMarket`.

```
function runATest<V, T extends AdvancedMarket<V>>(market: T, obj: V) {
  market.test(obj)
}
```

I know I can run the function without specifying the generic parameters, as they are inferred by the compiler:

```
const am1 = new AMarket1
runATest(am1, "Hello")
```

But let's suppose I would like to be explicit with the parameters, I would do something like:

```
runATest<string, AMarket2<string>>(am1, "Hello")
```

Now my question is, why do I have to be specific in marking the `string` `type` twice, `<string, AMarket2<string>>`, considering in the `function` declaration I already specify that `V` is the `generic` `type` passed to `AdvancedMarket` class: `<V, T extends AdvancedMarket<V>>`.

In other words, is there no way to avoid the redundancy of specifying the V type twice, by doing something like

```
runATest<string, AMarket2>(am1, "Hello")
runATest<AMarket2<string>>(am1, "Hello")
```

EDIT:

I might have another `generic` `class` which does not `extend` `AdvancedMarket`

```
class AMarket3<T> {
  test(t: T): void {
    console.log(t + "3")
  }
}
```

Thus I would do something like:

```
function runATest2<V, T extends {test(v: V): void}>(market: T, obj: V) {
  market.test(obj)
}

runATest2<string, AMarket3<string>>(am3, "hello")
```

Here I still would need to specify the `string` type twice.

Comment: Why is `runATest()` generic in two parameters anyway?  Is something wrong with  `function runATest<V>(market: AdvancedMarket<V>, obj: V)` ?

Comment: @jcalz Because this is just an example. I might want runATest() to be compatible with other types which do not extend AdvancedMarket but still take a generic parameter V.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand;  if you want it to be compatible with other types, then your code here won't work because you wrote `T extends AdvancedMarket<V>`.  Right now the example code doesn't motivate having two type parameters, and having more type parameters than necessary often leads to issues.  Maybe you could provide a [mre] that motivates the extra type parameter?

Comment: @jcalz Let me edit the question real quick

Comment: @jcalz I posted the edit.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic/60378737#60378737).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not seeing the point.  You can write `function runATest<V>(market: {test(v: V): void}, obj: V) {}` and use the same implementation.  [Observe](https://tsplay.dev/N9PkMw). What, specifically, is driving the need for a second type parameter?

Comment: @caTS I agree that in the absence of partial type argument inference (as per [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)) that something like currying would be necessary to specify one and infer another.  Or some other workaround.  But surely we need to see an actual use case for a second type parameter in the first place.

Comment: @jcalz I didn’t know you could implement such syntax in function arguments. What is the reason someone should constraint generics when they can do the same with function arguments then?

Comment: You could write `function getProp<T, K extends keyof T>(t: T, k: K): T[K]`, for example, where you care about *which* subtype of `keyof T` you get, so that you know *which* property type is returned.  If your function doesn't care about which subtype of `{test(v: V): void}` is passed in, then you don't need another type parameter.  So then, what do you want to see happen in this question?  Do you want to [edit] to remove the incorrect premise that you need 2 type parameters, or change it to something where such parameters are needed? Or do you want to delete the question? Or what? Let me know.