# Typescript requires all generics to be passed if at least one is passed. Any workaround?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

### Problem

I have this function

```js
const create = <S,D>(
  state: S,
  derivedStateResolver: (s:S) => D
) => {
  return {
    state,
    derived:derivedStateResolver(state)
  }
}
```

that i can consume like this

```js
const a = create(
  { count: 0},
  (s) => ({positive: s.count > 0})
);
```

but i can't consume like this

```js
type B_MyState = { count: null | number};

const b = create<B_MyState>( // TS Error: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
  {count: 1},
  (s) => ({positive: (s.count !== null) && s.count > 0})
);
```

### Question

Why is ok to pass 0 type generics but not 1 ?

### Desire

I'd like to keep last example way of consuming the function.
Any workaround ?

### Playground

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRMC8MA8BlANACIB8AFAFAwzSqIBcMBlMAJovAJYBuiLuUtAEqIIIADY94DUhDq4AlJmIxC5RRmUBvZkigBXeGBjaqVGmnzMqbTjxZ0b3XvyEjxkmQLTzmAX3L+5AD0AFQw5ACCAHQwAOog8ADWEOQhQeSgkLDImHBItBRUmnAgemBQDAAMvpZUMurKpJoADiAQHFBO0hBRoGWwAIQYWGB6YmKKAGST1L2l5TDK1T7yANzk5MhR5ohz-aswQUEwyHpQIMCtALbNYohoMADuCcmbUY52Ua3tnTwHR6dzpcQDc7g9nkkUhtQuEAEIxAByIFg8UhGwAKgBPZoiBAcZqwR7IBYAJhgAHNEGB2BxgDAAEZnJ7oZrICAQGDgMSYznUhmIYCnCDoYWZFjUAAWpTE4vp6A4YAAZuwkOLUukoNj0LCAPoAWUxLgeWGKfXKDFG4xgAB8YKMrnL4L51ploAzcggUGhsLqDUbEGRmJozRUYABGGrMepKGBNb4dLqxnohmBDEZjCYwaazFNLXwrdbBMLkADCMVRr3IsKZADEEvSOOLXXoruwYOcYM14CAuI22zkAOJUml0zU4qLq8hj9Al-WGrzoE0lfoWjM2u0tx3OjLgN10rCegpBkMMCMnDmzv0L2pJhqxlptBM8bp7BZpjfjKYzZPzWB5gvQsWhDli8ULVrAdbwA2Ta7i2bYdl2PZ9vAJwwEO1KcKOWoTmkU5aioc7+rkpq-quVq2vaW4urusAsDqCoJsgYj+gwhCEQuxEnuG26urRHr5GghSsPRYCMcx15RhAd5xo+vz0Emr6DMMH6ZtmP79IsMDLGohaASElBhAAkhy3ztPSdztiAMBXMgiTak8LxPB0UpMqy7IKuSMBkpSGG0hyMAAPwBQZQRAA)

Comment: See the [linked q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic).  Using the currying workaround from that answer gives you [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wj1GMW) for your example.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz , exactly what is was looking for. 
Your linked question acts as the "accepted" answer.