# Typescript function return type as the return type of the function in a param

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that accept a callback as the parameter, then the function will return the result of the callback.
The type returned by the first function is the return type of the callback function:

Here an example:

```
const useMethod = <
  Data,
  Error = unknown,
  TReturn = unknown,
>(
  fn: (options?: Options<Data, Error>) => TReturn,
  options?: Options<Data, Error>,
): TReturn => {
  return fn(options);
};

const callback1 = () => { return "Hello" }
const callback2 = () => { return {hello: "World"} }
const callback3 = () => { return 100; }

useMethod(callback1); // This will be string
useMethod(callback2); // This will be {hello: string}
useMethod(callback3); // This will be number
```

The issue I'm getting into is that if I pass a type to the first type argument, the return type became the default ( unknown in this case ) and not the one of the callback.

```
useMethod<{ param: string; }>(callback1); // This should be string but getting unknown
useMethod<string>(callback2); // This should be {hello: string} but getting unknown
useMethod<boolean>(callback3); // This should be number but getting unknown
```

Why this happen? How can I avoid this?
Thanks for any help

Comment: What is `Options`?  Please provide a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Assuming `Options<A, B>` is some structurally reasonable type like `{a: A, b: B}`, then your problem is that TypeScript doesn't currently support *partial type argument inference*, and for now you'd need to work around it.  The most common workaround is currying, as shown [in this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/wXzQLm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It is working in the playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgIIBooCEA+KAXigG8BDALilygCNb8BfAKDYGNU1goBXNBACyEYAAskAE1JQMbKFAAilYJRwKoAUQBOOpDtn8UAaxRIA7ig2KAKgCUx-HSiOnzVjYQAUmgGYotN5I8MjoAPy0cIg8GCpqeLr6OoQAlKTEDk4uNlAhMRFRobHx6tp6BoQaqbRZwM6uJMTkmjrZrgHBxeipANxsLP1cPHyclAA24wyUnCYAjLLe6U0UUG31LlAARAASEJNIW1Ds3OijE1MzJgBMi8vNa+0U4vvjSLRbAOoG41JbLMdhmcoGNJtNZgBmO4ZVbrBpQOYABkRvUBbEEIjEkik3lBl1mcz6UAA9MSoLZxAg0FALAhJoxoLwdAgUABzdFCUQSaS4i7gm5E0nkynU2n0hjQcgvA60Jks1knEaPDYoCCGMgYrnY3lgq4QwVkilUml08YMqAofgAWwlOg4QA)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript generics cannot be inferred partially
You either write no `<T>` at all, or `V` in `<T, V=D>` will be set do D as if you wrote `<T, D>` instead of inferring as you expect

[Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic)