# Create type from an Array parameter and use as a type in a mapping function

Tags: typescript

How do I map an array parameter to another parameter type.

An example of what I want is below:

```js
enum Item {
   A = 'A',
   B = 'B',
   C = 'C'
}
type ItemType = `${Item}`

type MappingFn = ( dependencies ) => string;

const createConfig = (dependencies: ItemType[], mappingFn: MappingFn) => {
 //
}

createConfig([ Item.A, Item.B ], (dependencies) => {
 // dependencies should be typed as Record<A | B, any>
  // ie I can access 'dependencies.A' or 'dependencies.B' but error with 'dependencies.C'
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `createConfig()` function should be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` corresponding to the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements of the `dependencies` parameter, [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `ItemType` if you want:

```
const createConfig = <K extends ItemType>(
  dependencies: K[],
  mappingFn: (dependencies: Record<K, any>) => string
) => {
  //
}
```

Let's see it in action:

```
createConfig(['A', 'B'], (dependencies) => {
  dependencies.A; // okay, any
  dependencies.B; // okay, any
  dependencies.C; // error, property C not known to exist
  return "wantsAString"
});
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgLsaBvAsAKClAglAvFAciwIBp1MAhPQi08qAYWoIYPQF904BPAB2FgIIAFT4D8AAwAkSeInYT06AMYB7EAGc4UZQCdgAQwQN1AMwCWAc2oAeANJRgADwQgAJhsGJR-AHwAKejdgfndQZXNgDQAuKDsAbQBdMgwoCANeXnMQSwAxEFj-YNDgkAio2IAlYDVdN3sSKAMQbl8ASjxfKC1dbMsO3C7UNE40FX0jYBMQC0t-eKJSGgJkqCKQ0FLyjQGhoI2wssiNADosAG4oAHorqFUAawNuRubufZLw45OKS5u7x+eTRa702nyiJwYv1uwF0ulUukavDh-F0PEYUBAqm090xAHcQFA4KpHE5zFp6Po4GBdASAES45pwDRYADKcF6OVpHDa5yAA)

Comment: Yeah this is similar to what I did. However, I have issue that it allows all keys not just the ones specified. I've updated my example as it's not 'string'.

Comment: Okay, updated. Hopefully the question stabilizes soon.

Comment: Thanks. It's weird I can see your example works as expected, but my actual implementation doesn't. Although it is a bit more complicated as I have another generic passed in the function. So then when I call the function K is expected to be defined.

Comment: That's a different issue, see [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218).