# How to enforce that some nested keys of an object are of a certain type?

Tags: typescript, validation

I'm looking for a type `Validate` that would enforce something like this

```
// validate
const myObj: Validate<'value', boolean> = {
   value: true,
   otherValue: 'its value',
   nestedProp: {
       value: false
   }
}

// does not validate
const myObj: Validate<'value', boolean> = {
   value: true,
   otherValue: 'its value',
   nestedProp: {
       value: 0 // not of type boolean
   }
}
```

Where the first parameter of the generic is the name of the nested property, and the 2nd is the type to enforce.

Is this even possible?

Edit: the idea is to get auto completition from the IDE when union types are used instead of `boolean` in that example.

```
type ColorType = 'red' | 'green'

type ColoredObject<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? ColoredObject<T[P]> : T[P];
} & { color: ColorType };

const myObject: ColoredObject<{ prop1: { prop2: { color: string } } }> = {
  color: 'red',
  prop1: {
    color: 'red',
    prop2: {
      color: 0 // this would fail
    }
  }
};
```

In the example above, it works the way I want it, but it makes the color attribute required. Is there a way to make it optional without breaking the requirement ? Also this requires me to pass the object interface as generic, which I do not want since I might not know it.

Edit2: Or this, but then it will not allow any other props than color

```
type ColoredObject<T, P, V> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object ? ColoredObject<T[P], P, V> : T[P] extends 'color' ? V : never
}

type ColorType = 'red' | 'green'
const test: ColoredObject<any, 'color', ColorType> = {
  color: 'green',
  otherProps: 'lala', // <---- fails here
  props: {
    color: 'green'
  }
}
```

Comment: The definition of the generic type you've asked for isn't even internally consistent. What behavior would you expect from `Validate<'value', { value: boolean; }>` for example?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4XqXW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining how it works; if not, what specifically am I missing (and could you [edit] the question to show use cases where it fails)?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz but this would only work for 2 level of nested object, and the 2nd level only validate for the `value` property, any other property names would fail. I need something that would work recursively.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to show use cases that should succeed and fail with however many levels of depth you'd need to distinguish between them?  It's possible a generic constraint and a helper function as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZQ7KN) would meet your needs, but I don't understand the use case well enough without more examples.

Comment: @jcalz the help function actually works quite well. Please submit it as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't obvious that, given a key type `K` and a value type `V`, that there is a specific type `Validate<K, V>` which exactly enforces the rule you're looking to enforce.  Often when it's difficult or impossible to write a specific type corresponding to some rule, it becomes a lot more straightforward to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type that *checks* if a candidate type obeys that rule.

So instead of `Validate<K, V>`, you use  `T extends Validate<T, K, V>` as a self-referential type [*constraint*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  And to prevent you from needing to manually specify that `T` type, you can write a generic helper function to *infer* it for you.

So conceptually the approach is: instead of `const x: Validate<K, V> = ...`, you write a function of the form

```
declare const validateKV = <T extends Validate<T, K, V>>(t: T) => t;
```

and then write `const x = validateKV(...);`.  Of course, it's not even *that* easy all the time; often `T extends Validate<T, K, V>` would be considered an illegally circular constraint, and to work around that you need to play games with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like

```
declare const validateKV = <T,>(
  t: T extends Validate<T, K, V> ? T : Validate<T, K, V>
) => t;
```

And you probably don't want to write a new helper function for every possible `K` and `V`, so that should be generic also, and unfortunately you can't get "partial inference" where you specify `K` and `V` but the compiler infers `V` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for the feature request) so you need to work around that (see [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218) for more information) and the easiest way is *currying*, like this:

```
const validate = <K extends PropertyKey, V>(k: K, v: V) =>
  <T,>(t: T extends Validate<T, K, V> ? T : Validate<T, K, V>) => t;
```

So that's what we'll use, once we define `Validate<T, K, V>`.

---

And here it is:

```
type Validate<T, K extends PropertyKey, V> =
  T extends object ? {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? V : Validate<T[P], K, V>
  } : T;
```

The idea is that, if `T` is a primitive type, then `Validate<T, K, V>` is just `T`.  So `Validate<T, K, V>` will automatically accept any primitive type.  On the other hand, if it is an object type, then `Validate<T, K, V>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property key `P` is checked.  If the property key `P` happens to be the same as the special key `K`, then we want to make sure that it has value type `V`.  Otherwise, we just want to recurse down and make sure that the property type `T[P]` is assignable to `Validate<T[P], K, V>` for the same `K` and `V`.

---

Let's test it out, for the particular `K` of `"value"` and `V` of `boolean`, as mentioned in the question code.  First we need to use the curried outer function:

```
const validateValueBoolean = validate("value", Math.random() < 0.5);
```

And now we can try that.

```
const myObj = validateValueBoolean({
  value: true,
  otherValue: 'its value',
  nestedProp: {
    value: false,
    nested: {
      value: true
    }
  },
  me: {
    value: true,
    other: 23,
    somethingElse: "",
    whoKnows: {
      foo: {
        value: true
      },
      value: false
    }
  }
}); // okay
```

That type checks as desired.  At every level, the property named `value` has a value of type `boolean`.  Contrast that with:

```
const myObj2 = validateValueBoolean({
  value: true,
  otherValue: 'its value',
  nestedProp: {
    value: false,
    nested: {
      value: true
    }
  },
  me: {
    value: true,
    other: 23,
    somethingElse: "",
    whoKnows: {
      foo: {
        value: 3 // error, number is not a boolean
      },
      value: false
    }
  }
});
```

This is a compiler error, and specifically on the bad `value` property, where it tells you that `3` is a `number` whereas a `boolean` was expected.  And if you fix that then the error goes away.

So, looks good. This is about as close as I can imagine getting to your desired type, given the limitations of the language and my understanding of the use case.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7AgHgCoBooDSUEAHhgHYoDOUACgE4D2k9oBEI+MAfFALwAoKFGzEyESjUYAjAFYQAxsCgB+KAG8hwqAG1aUJOSgBrDowBmIgLoAuOmIrVCq2FDvxkaDDj1X8BLm4tAF83EQBuAQEFRnIqZQA3RFR0aD4oTCJSRxoGZghWEHZOWG4ACmM7AKgE9wBKfiDhHFxy4DtRbIknDxTvPEJAl1F3ZK8sAeqeBr5eYEjo2PiasdSPAFcIACFGRgQIOCN0pM9UsoAiE83z-ABZdAALADp6Q5RGAFsyhswoAAYngBWOoLGJxZQfEAAeTk-BWpwwG22u32hzKmmEVwgdmA9E2uC0jGADwKSLsAHIkMAaFjyQThOQIPEICg8mA7BjtFi7OZEFQIPTtIzmSgOVptPDNji8RBxVBgiFBR9sRo5dyoLj8XKiST6HYAEwAZkFwionwgxMMAHMAKIIfl2c43OUAdwejAI5EYLqoYolwnMuz9-sxiClGplcuEwRNXLDKt59tlEoV0YEwRBUTBy0hMNk+rhJz6ECROz2B3I6K06s1AsJxNJ8YpVJp8bpWmFGFZTHZqol6sT-NjnZZwf7TYjmzlqflSpVnNDCHDtdjOoKBuNcrNyst5FtScdzolbo9Xp9Y+0gcYF-HS5VhqgAHpH8R6Ex6PhyOsPtICgYaF6yhwFA0gohWUazhBA58sm2gzgqGaREAA)

Answer (score 0):

what about that ?

```
type Validate<K extends string, T> = {
  value: boolean,
  otherValue: string,
  nestedProp:  {
    [key in K] :T
  }
}
```

---

Thanks to Titian comment

```
type Validate<K extends string, T> = {
      value: boolean,
      otherValue: string,
      nestedProp: Record<K, T>
    }
```

Comment: `{ [key in K] :T }` is equivalent to `Record<K, T>` I would prefer using the predefined mapped type instead of a custom one

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something generic, that could support a recursion of nested objects, and would work on any object without knowing its structure.