# TypeScript: return type overload based on callback parameters count

Tags: typescript

**Background:**

I'm tring to wrap a little helper, that will wrap react components either with `memo(fn)` or with `memo(forwardRef(fn)` based on the presense of optional `ref` parameter in the component definition. So baiscally:

```
Test((props)=>{}) // same as: memo((props)=>{})
Test((props, ref)=>{}) // same as: memo(forwardRef(props, ref)=>{});
```

**Issue:**

React details aside, let's consider this minimal example:

```
type AnyObject = Record<string, unknown>;
type EmptyObject = Record<string, never>;
type RenderResult = null; // `React.ReactElement | null` in real world
type RefType = string; // `React.ForwardedRef<T>` in real world

function Test<Props extends AnyObject = EmptyObject>(
    Component: (props: Props) => RenderResult
): (props: Props) => RenderResult;

function Test<Props extends AnyObject = EmptyObject>(
    Component: (props: Props, ref: RefType) => RenderResult
): (props: Props & { ref: RefType }) => RenderResult;

function Test(Component: (...args: any[]) => RenderResult) {
    // TODO: memo() / memo(forwardRef()) based on Component.length
    return Component;
}

type Props = { a: string };

// GOOD: typeof x === (props: Props) => null
// GOOD: typeof props === Props
const x = Test<Props>((props) => null);

// GOOD: typeof y === (props: Props & {ref: RefType}) => null
// BAD: typeof props === any
// BAD: typeof ref === any
const y = Test<Props>((props, ref) => null);
```

It almost works, but not quite. If you re-order the overload definition of the `Test`, the result is slightly different, but still not what I'm after (`ref` would be present in both `x` and `y`).

I have a vague feeling why this may happen (too much overlap? no way for TS to distinguish these two cases?), but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: This is a design limitation of TS described in [ms/TS#11936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11936); I'd *want* to work around it with generic conditional types, but you're already using manually specified generics so it wouldn't play nicely with that.  If I come up with something vaguely usable I'll let you know.

Comment: I'd say the "right" solution here is to just annotate the callback parameters yourself to sidestep the issue, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NV3J5m).  It isn't *much* more writing and it makes things behave.  Or you could try [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wo8Rew) which is complex but does, I think, work how you want.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Unfortunately, manual annotations of any kind wouldn't work for my use case. Passed props would be extended with more props based on element type, so one of the advantages of this little helper, is that you wouldn't need to manually add them. This is a full example: https://tsplay.dev/WG2lvm

Comment: @jcalz As I wrote in previous comment: "Passed props would be extended with more props based on element type, so one of the advantages of this little helper, is that you wouldn't need to manually add them.". This is why `FC<Props, 'div'>(props, ref)` would be acceptable but `FC(props: Props & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'div'>, ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLDIvElement>)` wouldn't. Sorry for making things confusing. I think I made main example a bit too minimal.

Comment: Okay so maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgD04N) (hopefully that's not the same as the other ones I sent) will work for you?  If so I could write up an answer.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Holy... This syntax is a bit freaky (reminds me of react-table), so I'm sure I won't settle for some imperfect simpler approach in this case, but I'm definitely interested in learning more about this hack nevertheless, so I'd appreciate an answer : )

Comment: I mean, [ms/TS#11936](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11936) is the problem, so anything you do will be working around that.  You've made things more constrained by essentially requiring that you get to pass a particular generic type argument into a function manually (and annotating function parameters isn't acceptable to you either), which means you can't use generic type inference, as described in [ms/TS#26242](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Currying is the cleanest workaround I know for that. I will write it up, but you want to relax a requirement somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a design limitation of TypeScript as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#11936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11936).  The type `(props: X) => Z` [is intentionally assignable to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) the type `(props: X, ref: Y) => Z`, so any code that tries to distinguish one from the other might be tricky.  Apparently the algorithm for resolving [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) gets tripped up over the similarity between them and fails to [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) your callback parameters.  Oh well.

---

So you'll have to work around it.  The *general purpose* workaround for failure to infer function parameters contextually is to [explicitly annotate them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) yourself, like

```
Test((props: Props, ref: RefType) => null);
```

but if that's not acceptable to you, you'll have to find another workaround.

---

One workaround when overloads don't work for callers is to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in the return type.  Something like

```
function foo(...args: Args1): Ret1;
function foo(...args: Args2): Ret2;
function foo(...args: Args3): Ret3;
```

can be transformed to something like

```
function foo<A extends Args1 | Args2 | Args3>(...args: A): 
  A extends Args1 ? Ret1 : A extends Args2 ? Ret2 : Ret3;
```

So when you call the new `foo()` the compiler infers `A` from the arguments, and then the return type is chosen based on that.

Unfortunately, you are already using generics in your overloads, and worse, you're manually specifying the type parameter when you call it.  The new generic function would have to have multiple type arguments, one of which you specify manually, and the other should be inferred.  But TypeScript doesn't support *partial type argument inference*, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  See [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218). So in order for this to work, we need to work around *that* limitation.

The cleanest such workaround is to use [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and split the single multi-type-param function into two single-type-param functions, so you manually specify the type argument when calling the first function, and this returns a second function which you call and the compiler infers the type argument for that one. It adds an extra function call for callers, which isn't ideal, but it's only a few extra parentheses (e.g., instead of `f<T>(x, y)` you have to write `f<T>()(x, y)`).

For your example, this looks something like:

```
function Test<P extends AnyObject = EmptyObject>():
    <F extends (props: P, ref: RefType) => RenderResult>(
        Component: F
    ) => (props: P & (
        Parameters<F>['length'] extends 0 | 1 ? unknown : { ref: RefType })
    ) => RenderResult;
```

So you call `Test<Props>()`, and that returns a function of type

```
<F extends (props: Props, ref: RefType) => RenderResult>(
    Component: F
) => (props: Props & (
    Parameters<F>['length'] extends 0 | 1 ? unknown : { ref: RefType })
) => RenderResult;
```

And you can see that the function infers `F` from `Component`, and if `F`'s parameter list is less than two arguments long, then the returned value is of type `(props: Props) => RenderResult`.  Otherwise, it is of type `(props: Props & {ref: RefType) => RenderResult`.

Note that means the implementation of `Test()` also needs to be changed so it's curried (at runtime this is really just returning a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)):

```
function Test() {
    return function (Component: (...args: any[]) => RenderResult) {
        // TODO: memo() / memo(forwardRef()) based on Component.length
        return Component;
    }
}
```

Well, let's test it:

```
type Props = { a: string };

const x = Test<Props>()(props => null);
// const x: (props: Props) => RenderResult

const y = Test<Props>()((props, ref) => null);
// const y: (props: Props & { ref: RefType; }) => RenderResult
```

It works! Those extra parentheses are there, but you get all the types you're looking for.

---

So there you go.  Maybe this workaround will meet your needs, but if not, you will probably have to settle for something else that doesn't do exactly what you want... at least until and unless there's ever a change to the overload resolution code as described in microsoft/TypeScript#11936.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiA8gIwFYQMbCgXigJUwHsAnAEwB4BnYEgSzgHMAaKAVzgGs4iB3OAHwBuAFChIUAKIBbMKBTosuAsXLVaDFlDgQAbhBLCx4aIThkDhKmwA22PHFs2hUAPSuoAA0IBDLADpfLEkbCGkIOGwAH20nTygGKBIIHxsoXlIbMmMJQgAzABUTZRp6Jhd3LyDgfwAxUl4fcggyfIoCgXjE5NT0zOyRETyOLDoiOCgCiBoKAAUoCAAPYAiyKlgEBUx7KVl5NG2BAAoASgAuESgrqApaheXV9aOwEiIwKjOoWdZkvM-8oqQE64AQqcyWaa2YDHS7XOEAYSIsnGEWAn1qsKuwJwoOer3en3mADIoEdMXCvk0fOEViQqLcBABtADkoSYwAAFsyALr3FbmdYABigMQAjFAAPzsLg8fhQT4AbySED+KkKxQAvidydjQWYLCQrFDRINhnBRuNJtNgKcoAryclgGwSBMzRaJkdEcidJFPkd-AGmowPlAfAhGdzdWCDUa7MD7RTrpUCogACKIT7haREW0eLM5vINJqtFWnYHIHxUFpQS1esAoyL+NmMTnkuGO50TOsN4CiOEakQDnLQWb49Z4JU+T6lTRQDUmjDjGhQRbKKYzUdvKjHE54rcg2I2GwnUSVRdwZeLP0vLeEsdR-UQ6x2Qbn5cgNfWuZjndHPfvH4VSjRwjxPEQzyXbAQGvMc733EklV+f4VUBCAXC1A9H0NSE7CAA)