# Is there a TypeScript solution that can force every attribute of the generic is in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

I have created this form builder that has a group of fields in a form layout

```
const form: FieldsGroupLayout<User> = [
  layout([
    field('firstName', 'John'),
    field('lastName', 'Doe'),
  ]),
  layout([
    field('age', 12),
    field('gender', 'Male'),
  ]),
];
```

I wanted to create a type check that will throw a type error if all attributes of the User interface have been represented in the nested fields. I have built this

```
type FieldValue<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

type Field<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  fieldName: K;
  value: T[K];
};

type FieldsGroupLayout<T> = Array<Array<Field<T, keyof T>>>;

function layout<T>(fields: Array<Field<T, keyof T>>): Array<Field<T, keyof T>> {
  return fields;
}

function field<T, K extends keyof T>(fieldName: K, value: T[K]): Field<T, K> {
  return {
    fieldName,
    value,
  };
}

interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
}

const form: FieldsGroupLayout<User> = [
  layout([
    field('firstName', 'John'),
    field('lastName', 'Doe'),
  ]),
  layout([
    field('age', 12),
    field('gender', 'Male'),
  ]),
];
```

This code only checks if the unknown attribute is in the field not if the attribute is missing.

Is it even possible to achieve this on the array? even the slightest hint is most welcome.

Comment: TS doesn't have a concept of an "exhaustive array"; you can jump through hoops to try to get the compiler to check that for you, like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVRxGN) maybe, but it's clunky, ugly, and fragile.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz This is amazing and works for the most part. but updating let's say layout function to return {fields: []} instead of an array of the field is giving me a hard time. 

It's an amazing piece of snippet tho

Comment: If you're trying to show an unmet use case please do so with a [mre] in the question instead of a verbal description of the problem in a comment (although if you have a [mre] in a comment that would be fine too, at least until we can [edit] it into the question).  Even if you can't get that code to meet your use case, it's sort of besides the point, because the main answer here is "no, that's not a type TypeScript can represent directly" and the generic helper functions are just workarounds and might well need to be tweaked for different use cases. How would you like to proceed?

Comment: You are right. [Here is the an example](https://tsplay.dev/mAxA4N) that I was using.

Comment: Okay but that's just a followup issue where you've changed what `layout()` outputs without changing what `fieldsGroupLayoutFor` expects.  I consider that out of scope for the question as asked; if you think otherwise then you should probably [edit] the question to describe the use cases you actually care about.  But I think it would be better to leave as-is, let me write up an answer here, and if you can't figure it out then you open a new question for it.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: okay, "answer here" instead of editing the question sounds good.

Comment: @jcalz [Here is my attempt](https://tsplay.dev/mpx4Xm) to modify fieldsGroupLayoutFor and Missing type

Comment: And [here](https://tsplay.dev/wO5nEm) is how I might fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have a native concept of "exhaustive array".  An array in TypeScript is always allowed to not contain every possible member of the contained type.  It's not really a very easy concept to convey to the compiler, either, since [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) exist, and it's not clear whether `[X, X, X]` counts as being exhaustive over `X` if `X` might turn out to be a union.  There was a closed feature request for native exhaustive array types at [microsoft/TypeScript#53171](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53171). In that issue it shows some approaches and links to some others, but none of them are particularly ergonomic.

If it is critical that you don't miss any members, you should add a runtime check in additional to any type magic.  But we can try some type magic.  Like this, maybe:

---

First we need to make `layout()` and `field()` try to keep track of exactly the `fieldName` and `value` properties that you pass to them, especially the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) types of the `fieldName` properties:

```
type Field<K extends PropertyKey, V> = {
    fieldName: K;
    value: V;
};

type FieldFor<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]-?: Field<K, T[K]> }[keyof T]

function layout<T extends readonly Field<any, any>[]>(fields: readonly [...T]) {
    return fields;
}

function field<K extends PropertyKey, V>(fieldName: K, value: V): Field<K, V> {
    return {
        fieldName,
        value,
    };
}
```

You can test that, for example, `field("abc", 123)` will be inferred as `Field<"abc", number>`.  Then we can write a `fieldsGroupLayoutFor` utility function that accepts your object type parameter `T` and produces a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that accepts an array of `layout()` outputs as type `U` and complains bitterly if `U` doesn't have all the fields from `T`.  Like this:

```
function fieldsGroupLayoutFor<T extends object>() {

    type Missing<T extends object, U extends readonly (readonly FieldFor<T>[])[]> =
        FieldFor<{ [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, U[number][number]['fieldName']>]: T[K] }>

    return function <U extends readonly (readonly FieldFor<T>[])[]>(
        u: U & (Missing<T, U> extends never ? unknown : readonly [Missing<T, U>])
    ) {
        return u as readonly (readonly FieldFor<T>[])[]
    }
}
```

And then test it:

```
interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
}

const fieldsGroupLayoutForUser = fieldsGroupLayoutFor<User>();
const form = fieldsGroupLayoutForUser([
    layout([
        field('firstName', 'John'),
        field('lastName', 'Doe'),
    ]),
    layout([
        field('age', 12),
        field('gender', 'Male'),
    ]),
]); // okay   

const badForm = fieldsGroupLayoutForUser([
    layout([
        field('firstName', 'John'),
        field('lastName', 'Doe'),
    ]),
    layout([
        // field('age', 12),
        field('gender', 'Male'),
    ]),
]); // error!
// Type 'readonly [Field<"firstName", string>]' is not 
// assignable to type 'Field<"age", number>'
```

That works.  It would have been nice if you could just call `fieldsGroupLayoutFor<User>([⋯])` instead of `fieldsGroupLayoutFor<User>()([⋯])`. but TypeScript doesn't currently allow for *partial* type argument inference where we manually specify `T` but the compiler infers `U`.  This is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) and the current best workaround involves a function-returning-a-function. See [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic).

Anyway, *how* it works is that the compiler looks at your array-of-arrays-of-`Field`s `U` and computes the union of `fieldName`s as `U[number][number]["fieldName"]`.  Then it computes `Missing<T, U>`, the union of `Field`s of `T` that are missing from `U[number][number]`, as `FieldFor<{ [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, U[number][number]['fieldName']>]: T[K] }>`.  If this is `never`, then `U` is okay.  If it has any members at all, then `U` is missing something.

The type of the `u` input to the returned function will either be `U`, if `U` is okay, or the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `U` and `readonly [Missing<T, U>]` if `U` is missing something. That leads to okay arrays being accepted, and bad arrays being rejected with an error message about the missing fields.

---

Again, that "works". But it's clunky and awful. And fragile too, since nothing stops you from manually sidestepping the check.  Arrays are just not required to contain elements, so you can assign a non-exhaustive array to the array type and pass it later without error:

```
const arr: readonly (readonly FieldFor<User>[])[] = [];
const whoops = fieldsGroupLayoutForUser(arr) // acceptable!
```

You can keep patching this to try to prevent such things, but it's ultimately a lost cause.  The compiler simply cannot enforce exhaustiveness.  So at some point you'll need to cut your losses and just either accept an unlikely yet possible runtime issue, or write more runtime checks than you'd like.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwDwGkoQB7AgO2QGcoAFAJwHtJzR0IQAaKANQD4oBeKAbwCgogqADMEKAHIBDALYQAXFHQBuAUIBukxAFd5rFQF8VfUJFhjkMSuVQAVDp1WCeUANqY4+KAGsGlYVBsAXQBaAH4FeCQ0dGYbN0COfRcfED8AwL4+YS18AGNgOEpPRElUrWBbLFwCYihyCElkIsQQMyjUSXwmKE6QNhcEgApRKKIFesbm1pcAOjmggEpeRzqIYC1yTxGUIgNM7LyCopFzDCq8QhIKaghaEHpu9mHzKVkFGKgNbV0WBYjTj7sZZCVbrTbAkFCbbIV4QRgrEFfHTwkGGPj6fY5fKFLbmIgAcSoWjAABlSpRypZrDZzjUSJQAEYAKwg+TYgyW-BWJmgAFk4EQiB4AOaVHAXWqMln5ZgAVVpl1Wk3wLSggwmTRVrUiKCptn6gQWA3sCKEOosVlQzjcUA83l8-hpkhIAFFsLltMgIBg5S58FppAzboE-QGg+QQwByaGwyMJQIKOLoQJQfRsTIg+pgrZYo6eVDy8V0pWa1Xqhql7XmPV2AZGoamwRaBTygBkav5gpFtjlHCLivwEDUtygoSgOS8+EoAHdPOMK1NXJ2hfhRTZe4aVpzG6CNp4tD0SBrF+XlarzTWDfWVhiMXwPHhyMJJLloLKiCP+CDROQiMBYQof7kCKKggiUf4AVAQEgSskjCro-qBrcoFCPBhC3IBwDAauex8LkRR-icoyEhSpLkpSVjviO3DQgSRJkWUwB6lR5DsgsKj4fghHCFY0hcEROwkcSZKMVSLGDC4KwlIxEk7tCgzRnAv7-jIECRswkYAFKUAAFvgkYLCikKCPJkbgSpsjqVAkYACKUGphkrIaRmCNJFLALJxkmeYClwWpzAAIwAEyOV5AnIApaFeuQVmRrymgOS5UDOXwhpGHhBHAFADKNFSfE0XiQkMe5YkfuQnlCG55QVcZpk-hBqmxdpekGUl34+WZzoWf51l2YlTmhZV5EeZJYUAPRjeFvnwVZwWDbVHVRbcsXxYg-UgilaVQBNWDkFQ5AAIR8DtNjgNAkbHlqrjmqgABE9XdbdzDQaubCBJGtokFOWXHZNzpCsK+CSAya1QMAlBg2d1k3bdflPVAiHhmwkaZBlXFZZIe3zmerSnpWbS6paLFXgM-EDBxmVQNOOmUNQJAFcR9EiSVlFlYMmPkEsO0vq+YDAMDa1AA)