# Convert an array to a type and pass it to another object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my code, but it doesn't work as I expect. I want to create schema using only IEntity as generic type, and auto forwarding groups name from Params to Fields.

```
interface TField<FieldName, GroupName> {
  name: FieldName;
  group?: GroupName;
}

interface TParams<GroupNames> {
  groups?: GroupNames;
}

function create<
  DataType,
  GroupNames extends Array<string>,
  // something like one of the following lines
  GroupName extends GroupNames[number]
  GroupName extends GroupNames extends Array<infer Type> ? Type : never
>(
  params: TParams<GroupNames>, 
  fields: TField<keyof DataType, GroupName>[]
) {
  return { params, fields };
}

export interface IEntity {
  uuid: string;
  title: string;
  number: string;
  status: string;
}

const entity = createSchema<IEntity>(  // I want to add only 1 argument
  {
    groups: ['main', 'additional'],  // first I fill groups
  },
  [
    { name: 'uuid' },
    { name: 'number', group: 'main' },  // next I want to get one of group here
    { name: 'title', group: 'main' },  // and here
    { name: 'status', group: 'additional' },  // and here
  ]
);
```

Comment: You can't pass "only 1" type argument to a generic function and have it work how you want; you need to pass all, or none.  See [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242). I expect this is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218).  If I use the currying workaround from that answer, I get [something like this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAPkXN).  Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?