# Typescript state machine that prevents dis-allowed transitions with compile errors

Tags: typescript, state-machine, typing

I am trying to create a state machine type where the transitions are enforced by the compiler.

I want to define the state machine like this:

```js
type States = {
    state1: {state: 'state1'},
    state2: {state: 'state2'}
}

const Transitions: TransitionsType<States> = {
    init() {
        return {state: 'state1'}
    },
    state1: {
        state2({...anyOtherItems}) {
            // processing with anyOtherItems
            // maybe return a load of extra stuff here
            return {...anyOtherItems, state: 'state2'}
        }
    },
    state2: {
        state1({...others}) {
            // same deal here
            return {state: 'state1'}
        }
    }
};

transition(transitions, {state: 'state1'}, 'state2');
```

States is a type that describes the states of the machine, and a datatype for that state.

Transitions is an object that has the *from* state as the first level of the map, and the *to* is the second level of the map. The functions will be called for each transition, and they will take the type related to the *from* state, and return the type related to the *to* state. The `init` function is to kick it all off.

`transition` is a function that takes a state machine definition, a state object and a *to* state, and returns a new state object.

I want to get compile errors if the transition functions return objects with the wrong states, and if the `transition` function is called with a state object and a *to* state that are disallowed.

So far I have (and feel free to completely ignore this):

```js
type StatesType<S> = {
    [T in keyof S]: {state: T};
};

type TransitionTosType<S extends StatesType<S>, F extends keyof StatesType<S>> = {
    [T in keyof S]?: (arg: S[F]) => S[T]
}

type TransitionsType<S extends StatesType<S>> = {
    [F in keyof S]: TransitionTosType<S, F>
} & {
    init: () => S[keyof S]
}

function transition<S extends StatesType<S>>(transitions: TransitionsType<S>,
                                            state: S[keyof S],
                                            to: keyof S & string): {state: string} {
    const fromStateTransitions = transitions[state.state as keyof TransitionsType<S>];
    if (fromStateTransitions) {
        const toTransition = fromStateTransitions[to];
        if (toTransition)
            return toTransition(state);
    }
    throw new TypeError(`no transition from ${state.state} to ${String(to)}`);
}
```

This gives me an error on the line `return toTransition(state);`, and it does not give me an error if I try to transition to a disallowed state.

I'd be happy to accept any answer that can take the states and transitions given (`States` and `Transitions` in the example), and provides a function which takes a set of transitions (e.g. `Transitions`), a state context of the correct type (as given in a type like `States`), and string for the transition *to*, and where there will be compile errors if the state context is the wrong type, or the *to* state isn't a valid transition from the *from* state.

I am fine with the transition function accepting type parameters.

I will also accept an explanation of why it is impossible as an answer.

Comment: I have reformatted, and broken it up. I have changed the type names to single char capitals. Can you suggest any more improvements to attract interest?

Comment: I think that is all of them.

Comment: Is `transitions` a typo? What use is `init()` here if you don't use it in your [mre]? Is there a reason why the only information in the state object is the name of the state?  Why not just `{state1: ["state2"], state2: ["state1"]}` for the transitions object? The more complex the data structure the harder it is to deal with and reason about.  Right now the only information in a state seems to be its name. I'd be inclined to collapse your whole example to [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NB1Lkw) but I have no idea if that meets your needs. How should we proceed?

Comment: I am aware that there are easier ways to solve this problem - I am interested in how to get the typing to work on this example. The functions in Transitions are supposed to be called on a transition, and the state holding objects are to be passed to the transition functions (I will modify the example to make that clearer). The functions then return the new state holder. So, if the transition is from `state1` to `state2`, the function at `Transitions['state1']['state2']` would get called.

Comment: I just worked on this for about 30 minutes and the typings for your current example are too complicated... mostly because you want the variable `Transitions` (it's a capital `T`, right? You still have a typo with `transitions` somewhere) to be of type `TransitionsType<States>` which forgets anything specific about which "to" states are accessible form which "from" states, and if we change it so that it remembers, then the list of available states isn't directly encoded anywhere in the type. (more)

Comment: (see prev comment, continued) Are you okay with a solution where you have to call `transition<States>()(Transitions, state, to)` to tell the compiler the list of states directly? It involves currying. I still feel like `init()` is a big complication that you're not using in the question, and it only serves to make the job of answering the question harder. How to proceed now?

Comment: I'd be happy to accept any answer that can take the states and transitions given (`States` and `Transitions` in the example), and provides a function which takes a set of transitions (e.g. `Transitions`), a state context of the correct type (as given in a type like `States`), and string for the transition _to_, and where there will be compile errors if the state context is the wrong type, or the _to_ state isn't a valid transition from the _from_ state. I am fine with that function accepting type parameters. I will also accept an explanation of why it is impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my point about currying.  If you allow currying I would suggest [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJBY6W). If that meets your needs I'd be happy to write up an answer; otherwise, can you explain what the problem is (e.g., why currying isn't acceptable)?

Comment: I do not understand why you have not suggested that as a solution. I agree that it is not _exactly_ what I asked for, but it is very close. If you do suggest it, I may not immediately accept it as the solution, because someone might have an even better one, but I will certainly mark it as the solution in a day or so otherwise. Also, I do accept that this problem may not have a _better_ solution. I asked the question because it was something that I couldn't solve in a nicer way than what I ultimately opted for (which is far cheaper and nastier, but works fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see with your code example is that you have a conflict between manually specifying that `transitions` is of type `TransitionsType<States>`, and allowing the compiler to infer something more specific from the initializing [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).  The type `TransitionsType<States>` has a fairly explicit representation of the `States` type, which you need for `transition(transitions, ⋯)` to function correctly.  But if you use that type then the compiler has no idea about the specifics of the state graph and which nodes are connected to which.  You really need to use a narrower type, such as shown here:

```
const transitions = {
  init() {
    return { state: 'state1' }
  },
  state1: {
    state2({ ...anyOtherItems }) {
      return { ...anyOtherItems, state: 'state2' }
    }
  },
  state2: {
    state1({ ...others }) {
      return { state: 'state1' }
    }
  }
} satisfies TransitionsType<States>;
```

where I've used [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to both verify the assignability to that type and to provide a [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) in which to infer the type of `transitions`.  That inferred type is:

```
const transitions: {
    init(): {
        state: "state1";
    };
    state1: {
        state2({ ...anyOtherItems }: {
            state: 'state1';
        }): {
            state: "state2";
        };
    };
    state2: {
        state1({ ...others }: {
            state: 'state2';
        }): {
            state: "state1";
        };
    };
}
```

But then the type of `transitions` doesn't explicitly contain the `States` type.  So you'd need `transition(transitions, ⋯)` to be able to tease apart the type of `transitions` to recover the original `States` type, which isn't necessarily fully present (imagine a graph where one of the states is disconnected).

There might be clever ways to get the best of both worlds here, but in my attempts the typing for `transition()` became so complex that it doesn't seem worth it to me.

---

Instead, my approach would be to accept that you need to explicitly pass two pieces of information to `transition()`: both the `States` type at the type level, and the specific shape of `transitions`.  Ideally then the call would look like

```
transition<States>(transitions, state, to);
```

But unfortunately, that type-level type passing would require what's known as "partial type argument inference" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26272](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), which isn't currently supported in TypeScript.  See [Typescript: infer type of generic after optional first generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218), for example.  The workarounds involve some refactoring. The most common one is a type-level [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) so that instead of `transition<States>(transitions, state, to)`, the call `transition<States>()` returns a function which you call with `(transitions, state, to)` as arguments.

It could look like this:

```
function transition<S extends StatesType<S>>() {

  function f<T extends TransitionsType<S>, F extends S[keyof S]>(
    transitions: T,
    state: F,
    to: keyof T[F["state"] & keyof T]
  ): void;

  function f(transitions: any,
    state: any,
    to: any): { state: string } {
    const fromStateTransitions = transitions[state.state];
    if (fromStateTransitions) {
      const toTransition = fromStateTransitions[to];
      if (toTransition)
        return toTransition(state);
    }
    throw new TypeError(`no transition from ${state.state} to ${String(to)}`);
  }
  return f;
}
```

So now when you call `transition<States>()`, the type of `S` inside the function is set in stone, and can be used to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` (the generic type corresponding to `transitions`, and `F` (the generic type corresponding to `state`), and consequently the type of `to` is an easily-written function of `F` and `T`.

That is, if `T` is the type of `transitions`, and `F` is the type of `state`, then `to` must be of type `keyof T[F["state"]]` (one of the keys of the property of `transitions` corresponding to the state `F`).  Note that I had to write `T[F["state"] & keyof T]` to convince the compiler that `F["state"]` is acceptable as a key of `T`. It's not *directly* written that this is true, at least not for generics, and the compiler can't deduce it.  An [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) frees up the compiler from worrying about it.

---

Okay, let's try it out:

```
const transitionFunc = transition<States>();
transitionFunc(transitions, { state: 'state1' }, 'state2'); // okay
transitionFunc(transitions, { state: 'state1' }, 'state1'); // error
transitionFunc(transitions, { state: 'state2' }, 'state2'); // error
transitionFunc(transitions, { state: 'state2' }, 'state1'); // okay
transitionFunc(transitions, { state: 'state3' }, 'state2'); // error
```

Looks good. The compiler only allows you to pass in arguments of the appropriate types, and will warn you if your `to` state is not directly accessible from `state`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIGcoF4oG8BQUrISQEYAuLfQiMgcgMQiOqgF8AaXC+gJjM06Rp0kXJs2xjsAYwD2AOwJRgAJ3jyAlsDVzUGHHjWyNACgCUWDniURgAVyWzyQqlFqVGLDmw5PS5vHicuIz4AOjDVEAB5YAALCCUASSQAW1RmMz1-S2s7B1Dw2SjY+KSIVNZ+Z1duUQsPPC8Ayh4-fx9gqDCQ6WKlNIy67Nt7R0pBN1qssQbxfEQ1ZAAzNRQoABUVdU1tNfAIAB44emQAPgBubCltYEVN5A0tWQAxG1lJdFvVe+3ZQ8pT0wXZRfB5yF5vIzAraPZAVPhOcb0dxsFyBagmM5QAD0WKg0gA1vAQNgod9HuDJJC7qD5HDKojiKIKtVGRjsbj4kppEoSdSfhSqSCfrDRvQGRARCxmWi2TioJzubyheTXpTSTSRfCxqjmkydUj0Zi5QSiUroWDVYLzbTRQJ9UgAMx6lkSw3s+VKLk8y4+0CQWD-XaQQ4nD6ZADaaygBig+IgIGki1gAF1ePT1iwLswLiS9us+Y81tJkEGDjB5QAPJCyAAmqCOSBLexDFSelerddj8cTAeOpZDod0HEj0YccYTSZgyYA-GQjPAlABzMgwcNPZNmNCh1drZPiS5+6AbZU7ZvliBViC1+uBs8nQetNejrsTlNkY-WotN4MwVsnWYAGStAYGhzpu27huOPZTvu2CLKqPyfNahztlenYNig-YwPepjmBw8FvIhiz7FGF4dqgH5kqeP4nK2qHXrAkHdpOyYnEYdTqsK77sFkCJQE8PH+MA0hkFBSZrGu4YAEROFJyZQEBYnrHueAmGQABu0hqDWOZ4ARkhEVaVHyGQESCU0YpQGZHEiVZhRqbazgEEoBiLiwrR4DI8g3IsXLJBhlEah8nEwuGTghE4yYXFkahJkYvnSP5lCBcKAxZJ51yKNIKWPB8CVJfQOXaOGwlRYM0ZxcJRWyCY5VDLkWXVUYTgYnU0xCTEXIAO5QLIEA9aWACinrckYAAGsjSEhxlQPlUAACSYOFTjMFlC2YHALmyIukLSCYzBja1Mz1SMixZtgQA)