# How strongly type nested object keys with generics in Typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, microservices, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to strong type communication between microservices in NestJS.

Pretty straightforward typing idea, I have this object which represent possible ways to call a microservices with their input(args) / result(return) values.

```
export type CompanyExpectedRoleAndCmd = {
      'company': {
        'find-unique': {
          input: number;
          result: string;
        };
        'find-many': {
          input: string;
          result: number;
        };
    
        'find-update': {
          input: string | number;
          result: number;
        };
      };
      'company-employee': {
        'find-unique': {
          input: string;
          result: Array<string>;
        };
      };
    };
    
export type EmployeeExpectedRoleAndCmd = {
      'employee': {
        'find-unique': {
          input: string;
          result: number;
        };
        'find-many': {
          input: number;
          result: string;
        };
    
        'find-update': {
          input: string;
          result: Array<number>;
        };
      };
      'employee-provider': {
        'find-unique': {
          input: number;
          result: Array<string>;
        };
      };
    };


export type ServiceTCP = {
  company: CompanyExpectedRoleAndCmd;
  employee: EmployeeExpectedRoleAndCmd;
  // And more...
};
```

**How is it working**

`ServiceTCP` will defined each Microservice scope, where each values for keys is all ways I can interact with this Microservice.

Here is a pretty simple way to strong type such object.

```
export type ServiceKeys = keyof ServiceTCP;

export type ServiceRoleAndCmd<T extends ServiceKeys> = keyof ServiceTCP[T];

export type ServiceRole<
  T extends ServiceKeys,
  K extends ServiceRoleAndCmd<T>,
> = keyof ServiceTCP[T][K];

export type ServiceCmd<
  T extends ServiceKeys,
  K extends ServiceRoleAndCmd<T>,
  C extends ServiceRole<T, K>,
> = keyof ServiceTCP[T][K][C];

export type ServiceInput<
  T extends ServiceKeys,
  K extends ServiceRoleAndCmd<T>,
  C extends ServiceRole<T, K>,
> = T extends keyof ServiceTCP
  ? K extends keyof ServiceTCP[T]
    ? C extends keyof ServiceTCP[T][K]
      ? ServiceTCP[T][K][C] extends { input: infer I }
        ? I
        : never
      : never
    : never
  : never;

export type ServiceResult<
    T extends ServiceKeys,
    K extends ServiceRoleAndCmd<T>,
    C extends ServiceRole<T, K>,
    > = T extends keyof ServiceTCP
    ? K extends keyof ServiceTCP[T]
        ? C extends keyof ServiceTCP[T][K]
            ? ServiceTCP[T][K][C] extends { result: infer R }
                ? R
                : never
            : never
        : never
    : never;

export type Pattern<
  T extends ServiceKeys,
  R extends ServiceRoleAndCmd<T>,
  C extends ServiceRole<T, R>,
> = {
  role: R;
  cmd: C;
};
```

**Problem**

This types definition is working perfectly fine, but I think this is not using Typescript efficiently.

Like here is the function I want to implement to communicate between microservices.

```
const sendMessageTCP = async <
  T extends ServiceKeys,
  R extends ServiceRoleAndCmd<T>,
  C extends ServiceRole<T, R>
>(
  pattern: Pattern<T, R, C>,
  input: ServiceInput<T, R, C>,
): Promise<ServiceResult<T, R, C>> => {
  /// For the example casting the manually
  return {} as ServiceResult<T, R, C>;
};
```

But if I want to call this I would have to specify EACH type of each key, which is redundant

```
const result = sendMessageTCP<'company', 'company', 'find-many'>(
    { role: 'company', cmd: 'find-many' },
    'string',
);
// result is a string there
```

And I really want to have something like this, and still have the correct type associated to them.

```
const result = sendMessageTCP<'company'>(
    { role: 'company', cmd: 'find-many' },
    'string',
);
// result is a string there
```

Comment: You are right I added comment, but even though Typescript recognize an issue for ServiceResult and ServiceInput, the type definition is still correct. (No idea why)

Comment: Anyway if I try to ignore that stuff (but pls do fix it) I'd say this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377365/typescript-infer-type-of-generic-after-optional-first-generic) and there's no direct support for it. The most common workaround is currying, where you add a function call in between, like `sendMessageTCP<'company'>()(⋯)` instead of `sendMessageTCP<'company'>(⋯)`.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGGxKW). Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Everything is fixed (mb), I get your idea but why wrapping the function will help in any way ? The problem will be left to the wrapper instead of the caller, which doesn't solve it at all. 
I don't see where this is a duplicate, can you explain it a bit more ?
I don't want to apply the same type.

Comment: Wow, ok, I have no clue you could, such thing in JS.
Yes, you are right it's solving the problem,  and it's pretty decent.
Do you have any other workarounds that you would recommend or resource about it?